# Using a Python Dictionary as a Key (Non-nested)

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

Python doesn't allow dictionaries to be used as keys in other dictionaries. Is there a workaround for using non-nested dictionaries as keys?

The general problem with more complicated non-hashable objects and my specific use case has been [moved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611797/using-non-hashable-python-objects-as-keys-in-dictionaries/1612220#1612220). My original description of my use case was incorrect.

Comment: The sort is necessary as python dictionaries are not ordered by default

Comment: This looks to me like a design problem. Can you give an example where it makes sense to use a dictionary as a key?

Comment: I think the function should take named tuples (or class instances) instead of nested dicts. You wouldn't have that problem then.

Comment: I guess you meant `sorted`, and it returns a generator so you need to make a `list` out of it.

Comment: Your exact use case sounds exactly like memoization.  There are recipes for that, and one of your answers suggests it.  If I am just not understanding, could you explain why you don't just use a memoize recipe?

Comment: One key thing that I want to be able to do is allow a function to memorize other results. For example if I have a function to calculate the average, then it will also calculate a standard deviation at the same time and I want to store both of these values and to be able to access one when I have want="stddev" and another when as want="average"

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you have a really immutable dictionary (although it isn't clear to me why you don't just use a list of pairs: e.g. `[('content-type', 'text/plain'), ('host', 'example.com')]`), then you may convert your `dict` into:

1. A tuple of pairs. You've already done that in your question. A `tuple` is required instead of `list` because the results rely on the ordering and the immutability of the elements.

   ```
   >>> tuple(sorted(a.items()))
   ```
2. A frozen set. It is a more suitable approach from the mathematical point of view, as it requires **only the equality relation** on the elements of your immutable `dict`, while the first approach requires the ordering relation besides equality.

   ```
   >>> frozenset(a.items())
   ```

Comment: +1: Good point on ordering.  A dictionary can always be transformed to a frozenset because the keys must be unique, assuring each tuple will be preserved in the set.  Elegant.

Comment: This is a nice solution which is more general than than the specific problem I posed, but doesn't this doesn't handle dictionaries within dictionaries.

Comment: Now moved this to a new question

Comment: Note that, Frozen set solution will not work, if the dict contains list or any other mutable object as values. For ex: a={'key1': 'val1', 'key2': ['val2', 'val3']}

Answer (score 8):

If I needed to use dictionaries as keys, I would flatten the dictionary into a tuple of tuples.

You might find this SO question useful: [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python)

And here is an example of a flatten module that will flatten dictionaries: http://yawpycrypto.sourceforge.net/html/public/Flatten.Flatten-module.html

I don't fully understand your use case and I suspect that you are trying to prematurely optimize something that doesn't need optimization.

Comment: +1: `tuple( someDictionary.items() )` works really, really well for making a dictionary into an immutable key.

Comment: Make that `tuple(sorted(somedictionary.items())` - the order of keys is not guaranteed, which means equal dicts might produce different reprs by listing the items in a different order.

Comment: Sorting in important. To see why you have to find 2 different key values with equal hash (it's probably hard to find for strings, but can be easily achieved with user defined objects), then construct 2 equal dictionaries by inserting them in different order. You'll get equal dictionaries with different order in `.items()`.

Comment: The difficulty with this is that each dictionary has to be sorted

Answer (score 7):

To turn a someDictionary into a key, do this

```
key = tuple(sorted(someDictionary .items())
```

You can easily reverse this with `dict( key )`

Comment: +1, though I find my solution with `frozenset` more "correct", see my answer.

Comment: `tuple(sorted())` will work as long as the dict's keys are comparable. `frozenset` requires hashable dict values.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be to subclass the dict and provide a hash method.  ie:

```
class HashableDict(dict):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.iteritems())))

>>> d = HashableDict(a=1, b=2)
>>> d2 = { d : "foo"}
>>> d2[HashableDict(a=1, b=2)]
"foo"
```

However, bear in mind the reasons why dicts (or any mutable types) don't do this: mutating the object after it has been added to a hashtable will change the hash, which means the dict will now have it in the wrong bucket, and so incorrect results will be returned.

If you go this route, either be **very** sure that dicts will never change after they have been put in the other dictionary, or actively prevent them (eg. check that the hash never changes after the first call to `__hash__`, and throw an exception if not.)

Comment: Overriding all mutating methods to raise an error will catch mistakes earlier at the cost of more code.

Comment: Again, this is a solution to the more specific problem, but the more general problem is open

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, isn't your use case just memoizing function calls? Using a decorator, you will have easy support for arbitrary functions. And yes, they often pickle the arguments, and using circular reasoning, this works for non-standard types as long as they can be pickled.

See e.g. [this memoization sample](http://www.finalcog.com/python-memoise-memoize-function-type)

Answer (score 1):

I'll sum up the options and add one of my own,
you can :

- make a subclass to dict and provide a hash function
- flatten the dict into a tuple
- pickle the dict
- convert the Dict into a string using the json module (as shown below)

```
import json
Dict = {'key' :'value123'}
stringifiedDict = json.dumps(Dict)
print(stringifiedDict)
# {"key": "value123"}
newDict = {stringifiedDict: 12345}
print(newDict[stringifiedDict])
# 12345
for key, val in newDict.items():
    print(json.loads(key))
    # {'key': 'value123'}
    print(json.loads(key)['key'])
    # value123
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd ever want to do this, but if you really really do need to, you could try pickling the dictionary:

```
mydict = {"a":1, "b":{"c":10}}
import pickle
key = pickle.dumps(mydict)

d[key] = value
```

Comment: This solves nesting, but does it do if the values are non-standard types? Does it pickle the values as well?

Comment: IMO, serialization is an overhead here. And @Casebash made a good point by mentioning the problem with non-standard types.

Answer (score 0):

this function will convert a nested dictionary to an immutable tuple of tuples which you can use as a key:

```
def convert_dictionary_tuple(input_dict):
    """
    this function receives a nested dictionary and convert it to an immutable tuple of tuples with all the given
    dictionary data
    :param input_dict: a nested dictionary
    :return: immutable tuple of tuples with all the given dictionary data
    """
    tuples_dict = {}
    for key, value in input_dict.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            tuples_dict[key] = convert_dictionary_tuple(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            tuples_dict[key] = tuple([convert_dictionary_tuple(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v for v in value])
        else:
            tuples_dict[key] = value

    return tuple(sorted(tuples_dict.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Class name... OK :/*

My solution is to create a class, with ***dict*** features, but implemented as a list with `{key, value}` objects. **key** and **value** can be anything then.

```
class DictKeyDictException(Exception):
    pass


class DictKeyDict():

    def __init__(self, *args):
        values = [self.__create_element(key, value) for key, value in args]
        self.__values__ = values

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.set(key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__values__)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        keys = self.keys()

        if key in keys:
            index = keys.index(key)
            del self.__values__[index]

    def clear(self):
        self.__values__ = []

    def copy(self):
        return self.__values__.copy()

    def has_key(self, k):
        return k in self.keys()

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            raise DictKeyDictException(f"no kwargs allowed in '{self.__class__.__name__}.update' method")
        for key, value in args:
            self[key] = value

        return self.__values__

    def __repr__(self) -> list:
        return repr(self.__values__)

    @classmethod
    def __create_element(cls, key, value):
        return {"key": key, "value": value}

    def set(self, key, value) -> None:
        keys = self.keys()

        if key in keys:
            index = keys.index(key)
            self.__values__[index] = self.__create_element(key, value)
        else:
            self.__values__.append(self.__create_element(key, value))

        return self.__values__

    def keys(self):
        return [dict_key_value["key"] for dict_key_value in self.__values__]

    def values(self):
        return [value["value"] for value in self.__values__]

    def items(self):
        return [(dict_key_value["key"], dict_key_value["value"]) for dict_key_value in self.__values__]

    def pop(self, key, default=None):
        keys = self.keys()

        if key in keys:
            index = keys.index(key)
            value = self.__values__.pop(index)["value"]
        else:
            value = default

        return value

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        keys = self.keys()

        if key in keys:
            index = keys.index(key)
            value = self.__values__[index]["value"]
        else:
            value = default

        return value

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.keys())
```

and usage :

```
dad = {"name": "dad"}
mom = {"name": "mom"}
boy = {"name": "son"}
girl = {"name": "daughter"}

# set
family = DictKeyDict()
family[dad] = {"age": 44}
family[mom] = {"age": 43}
# or
family.set(dad, {"age": 44, "children": [boy, girl]})
# or
family = DictKeyDict(
    (dad, {"age": 44, "children": [boy, girl]}),
    (mom, {"age": 43, "children": [boy, girl]}),
)

# update
family.update((mom, {"age": 33}))  # oups sorry miss /!\ loose my children

family.set({"pet": "cutty"}, "cat")
del family[{"pet": "cutty"}]  # cutty left...

family.set({"pet": "buddy"}, "dog")
family[{"pet": "buddy"}] = "wolf"  # buddy was not a dog

print(family.keys())
print(family.values())
for k, v in family.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether I understand your question correctly, but i'll give it a try

```
    d[repr(a)]=value
```

You can interate over the dictionary like this

```
for el1 in d:
        for el2 in eval(el1):
                print el2,eval(el1)[el2]
```

Comment: I think repl(a) would be better here as str might not be unique

Comment: `repr` of the different objects might not be different. The "difference" among Python objects is usually coded as `__eq__`, not `__repr__`.

Comment: `repr` and `str` are actually the same for dicts anyway.  However, you could run into trouble this way - it's possible to get dicts with different internal state so that, while they contain the same items, they list their keys in a different order, and would thus produce a different key.  You'll also run into trouble if you store objects without the property that `repr(x)==repr(y)` <=> x==y in the dict (eg. most user created classes).

Comment: -1: Use `tuple( someDictionary.items() )` instead of `repr`.  it gives you a structure that can be trivially transformed back into a dictionary without resorting to `eval`.

Comment: This won't work when you get hash collision. See my comment to other answer to see how to demonstrate the problem.