# Create a dictionary in python which is indexed by lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary which is indexed by lists. For instance, my dictionary should look like:

```
D = {[1,2,3]:1, [2,3]:3}
```

Anyone know how to do this? If I just type `D([1,2,3]) = 1` it returns an error.

Comment: that's not possible, dict keys need to be immutable. use tuples instead.

Comment: Well how would I do that? D((1,2,3))=1 also returns an error.

Comment: It looks like you are using `(...)` when you mean to use `[...]`. `D[1, 2, 3] = 1` should work fine.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611797/using-non-hashable-python-objects-as-keys-in-dictionaries

Answer (score 20):

dict keys must be *hashable*, which lists are not becase they are *mutable*. You can change a list after you make it. Think of how tricky it would be to try to keep a dict when the data used as keys changes; it doesn't make any sense. Imagine this scenario

```
>>> foo = [1, 2]
>>> bar = {foo: 3}
>>> foo.append(4)
```

and you will see why Python does not try to support lists as keys.

The most obvious solution is to use tuples instead of lists as keys.

```
>>> d = {[1, 2, 3]: 1, [2, 3]: 3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> d = {(1, 2, 3): 1, (2, 3): 3}
>>> d
{(2, 3): 3, (1, 2, 3): 1}
>>> d[2, 3]
3
```

Comment: You mean dictionary keys, not tuple keys, in the first sentence.

Comment: "try to keep a dict" => "try to keep a dict valid"

Comment: Just remember: Python doesn't know the difference between (1, 2) and (2, 1) when hashed... I had to create a class that can do this: https://gist.github.com/rjurney/d7913221dd38bee9708716f50c3c002e

Comment: @rjurney I think you're a little confused. What do you mean "Python doesn't know the difference between (1, 2) and (2, 1) when hashed"? (BTW, your class claims to take sets but isn't at all sensible for sets.)

Comment: @rjurney - I'm getting a key error when I run `d={(1, 2): 3}; print(d[(2, 1)])` on both 2.7.6 and 3.4. You should probably check it again.

Comment: @rjurney: Your point is true for sets (where (2,1) and (1,2) specify the same set).  It's not true for tuples: `print hash((1,2)), hash((2,1))` yields `3713081631934410656 3713082714465905806`

Comment: Note that it's possible in Python to create a class whose objects are mutable but are hashable.  It's a *very bad idea* and breaks underlying assumptions, though, so don't do it!  See https://www.asmeurer.com/blog/posts/what-happens-when-you-mess-with-hashing-in-python

Comment: @MikeGraham thanks for the nice examples.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary keys can be only hashable objects.
If you want the content of a list as a key you can convert the list to a tuple.

```
>>>d={}
>>>a = tuple((1,2))
>>>a
(1, 2)
>>>d[a] = 3
>>>print d
{(1, 2): 3}
```

Comment: Keys must be *hashable*, not necessarily *immutable*. You can have mutable values that are hashable (although it's rarely useful) and immutable values that are not hashable (for example, tuples that contain unhashable values.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, though was the same thing... could you give an example of mutable and hashable?

Comment: For an object to be sanely hashable, the answers it gives when you take its hash and do an equality comparison should never change. The actual object may be able to change in other ways. For example, if I had a class `Person` for defining persons, I may be able to use identity comparison for finding if two `Person` objects are equal no matter if I change things about a `Person`, like their age or address. If the mutability doesn't affect the calculation of equality and hash, it does not keep an object from being hashable.

Comment: @Mike, Thanks for the answer, I just wrote the same question as a new SO question.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {repr([1,2,3]): 'value'}

{'[1, 2, 3]': 'value'}
```

As explained by others [(see also here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257588/why-cant-i-use-a-list-as-a-dict-key-in-python), you cannot use a list directly. You can however use its string representation instead if you really want to use your list.