# Explanation needed regarding explanation of hashable objects

Tags: python, hash

[Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) answered on a [SO question about hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671376/hashable-immutable/2671476#2671476) here in SO:

> [...] An
>   object is hashable if it has a hash value **which never changes during
>   its lifetime**. So by the official definition, anything mutable can't
>   be hashable, even if it has a `__hash__()` function. My statement
>   about both requirements being necessary is untrue, because being
>   hashable already implies the requirement to be immutable.

I want to make sure, that I got that right - even as a non native speaker - so I hope someone corrects me if I got it wrong.

Assuming this class

```
class Author(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, age):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id==other.id\
               and self.name==other.name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(('id', self.id,
                     'name', self.name))
```

I understand, that `__eq__` allows me to compare objects of this class with the `==` operator. From Marks answer I understand, that even if my object `peter = Author(1, "Peter", 33)` has a `__hash__` it is not hashable because I potentially could do something like `peter.age = 43` which means it is not immutable. So my objects of the class `Author` are not hashable and therefore not usable as keys in dictionarys for example? Did I get right or does it seem, that I need more explanation? :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instances of this class are hashable if you *promise* never to reset `id` or `name` on them. You can't guarantee that these attributes will never be reset, by the Python principle that ["we are all consenting adults here"](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html), but it would be very bad style to offer methods that reset the attributes that `__hash__` relies on.

E.g., if you offer a `set_name` method on instances of `Author`, but no `set_id`, then clients of the class can reasonably presume that `__hash__` operates **only** on the `id`.

If you want to make it clear to clients of `Author` that they should not reset some attribute, you can label it private by prepending an `_` to its name. If you then still want to offer (read-only) access to the attribute using its common name, you can make it a [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Author(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, age):
        self._id = id
        self._name = name
        self.age = age      # ages tend to change, so mutable

    id = property(lambda self: self._id)
    name = property(lambda self: self._name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id==other.id\
               and self.name==other.name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(('id', self.id,
                     'name', self.name))
```

Comment: if I change `age` the object is seen as *not altered*?

Comment: @Druss: yes, since you're not considering it when determining equality or hash key. I'll update the answer with one more suggestion in a sec.