# How to test for "immutability-at-any-depth" in Python?

Tags: python, nested, immutability, hashable

I'm defining a Python object as being "immutable at any depth" iff

1. it is (nominally) immutable; *and*
2. if it is a "container" object, then it contains only objects that are "immutable at any depth";

For example `((1, 2), (3, 4))` is immutable at any depth, whereas `((1, 2), [3, 4])` isn't (even though the latter, by virtue of being a tuple, is "nominally" immutable).

> Is there a reasonable way to test whether a Python object is "immutable at any depth"?

It is relatively easy to test for the first condition (e.g. using `collections.Hashable` class, and neglecting the possibility of an improperly implemented `__hash__` method), but the second condition is harder to test for, because of the heterogeneity of "container" objects, and the means of iterating over their "contents"...

Thanks!

Comment: I think such a check is neither possible in general nor very useful. Do you have any use case in mind?

Comment: Why does being hashable mean being immutable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671376/hashable-immutable

Comment: More to the point, a hashable object would ideally be immutable but only built-in types actually guarantee that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no general tests for immutability.   An object is immutable only if none of its methods can mutate the underlying data.

More likely, you're interested in hashability which usually depends on immutability.  Containers that are hashable will recursively hash their contents (i.e. tuples and frozensets).  So, your test amounts to running `hash(obj)` and if it succeeds then it was deeply hashable.

IOW, your code already used the best test available:

```
>>> a = ((1, 2), (3, 4))
>>> b = ((1, 2), [3, 4])
>>> hash(a)
5879964472677921951
>>> hash(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you're looking for something like this:

```
def deeply_hashable(obj):
    try:
        hash(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    try:
        iter(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return True
    return all(deeply_hashable(o) for o in obj)
```

One obvious problem here is that iterating over a `dict` iterates over its keys, which are always immutable, rather than its values, which is what you're interested in. There is no easy way around this, aside of course from special-casing `dict` -- which doesn't help with other classes that might behave similarly but are not derived from `dict` At the end, I agree with delnan: there's no simple, elegant, general way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about what you are looking for exactly. But using your example data:

```
>>> a = ((1, 2), (3, 4))
>>> b = ((1, 2), [3, 4])
>>> isinstance(a, collections.Hashable)
True
>>> isinstance(b, collections.Hashable)
True
```

Hence, indeed using `collections.Hashable` isn't the way to go. However,

```
>>> hash(a)
5879964472677921951
>>> hash(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So, at least for the example data, using `hash` is enough to verify if the an object is hashable. Of course, as you already pointed out in your question, if `__hash__` is incorrectly implemented for a subclass of, let's say, `list`, then this check won't work.

Answer (score 1):

**It absolutely makes sense to have such a test!**

Consider the time of 'deepcopy()-ing' (or manually clone()-ing) 
an object versus a simple reference assignment!

Imagine two entities need to own one and the same object, but
rely on that it is not changed (dict-keys are a good example).

Then, it is only safe to use a reference assignment, if and only
if the immutability can be verified.

I would consider to recursively test for something like

```
def check(Candidate):
    if isinstance(Candidate, (str, int, long)):
        return True
    elif isinstance(Candidate, tuple):
        return not any(not check(x) for x in Candidate)
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I completely agree with the need for immutability test. And I like your recursive test. But it works only with a limited number of built-in types. I am thinking if it is possible to extend it for user defined classes... i.e. test if all methods do not change the object. But how to test that? Any idea?