# In python, how to check if a list of lists has duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I searched for the answer to my question and found that many said to try `set(my_list)`, but in my case (I have lists within a list) python throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Users/Rene/PycharmProjects/vaip/Main.py", line 17, in <module>
  set(punktid)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So my question is, how can I find and remove duplicates in a list like this:

```
my_list = [[0, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6], [9, 2], [0, 3]]
```

Comment: This question might help to understand the whole hashing thing: [Hashing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671376)

Answer (score 3):

Converting all sublists to tuples makes it possible to create `set` (all elements become hashable):

```
>>> {tuple(x) for x in my_list}
{(5, 6), (9, 2), (0, 3), (3, 4)}
```

In this case we use braces to denote a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), though it's also possible to use ordinary [set constructor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
>>> set(tuple(x) for x in my_list)
{(5, 6), (9, 2), (0, 3), (3, 4)}
```

If your final result must be a list of lists (the order may not be preserved):

```
>>> [list(y) for y in {tuple(x) for x in my_list}]
[[5, 6], [9, 2], [0, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that `{...}` instantiates the stuff inside as a set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
>>> l
[[0, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6], [9, 2], [0, 3]]
>>> def remove_duplicate(l):
    tup = [tuple(x) for x in l]
    set_tup = set(tup)
    return [list(x) for x in list(set_tup) ]

>>> print remove_duplicate(l)
[[5, 6], [9, 2], [0, 3], [3, 4]]
```