# Python dictionary key not updated when executing bounded method

Tags: python, dictionary, object, methods, key

I'm trying to update a key from a python object via a subscriber/pattern, this is part of a larger code base but I would like to check if I'm doing something wrong here.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
 
@dataclass
class A:
    a:float=2
    def mod(self,name):
        self.a = name
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.a)
```

```
class B:
    x = {}
    def attach(self,object):
        self.x[object]= getattr(object,'mod')

    def dispatch(self):
        for _, val in self.x.items():
            val(3)
```

When executing

```
>>>a = A()
>>>b = B()
>>>print(a.a)
>>>b.attach(a)
>>>print(b.x)
```

As expected:

```
{A(a=2): <bound method A.mod of A(a=2)>}
```

```
>>>print(b.x[a])
```

```
<bound method A.mod of A(a=2)>
```

Then when executing the update

```
>>b.dispatch()
>>print(b.x)
```

```
{A(a=3): <bound method A.mod of A(a=3)>}
```

But when the key is verified:

```
>>>print(list(b.x.keys())[0] is a)
```

```
True
```

When trying to retrieve the method

```
>>>print(b.x.get(a))
```

```
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem comes from the way hash is defined. Hashing should respect some properties. Dictionaries require hashable keys according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340756/python-why-can-i-put-mutable-object-in-a-dict-or-set)

From the [Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass)

> Having a **hash**() implies that instances of the class are immutable. Mutability is a complicated property that depends on the programmer’s intent, the existence and behavior of **eq**(), and the values of the eq and frozen flags in the dataclass() decorator.