# Simultaneous column assignment

Tags: python, pandas, variable-assignment

I just found that I can't assign like this:

```
df[['a','b','c']] = 'total'
```

or

```
df.loc[:, ['a','b','c']] = 'total
```

However, I can do

```
df['a'] = 'total'
df['b'] = 'total'
df['c'] = 'total'
```

or

```
df['a'] = df['b'] = df['c'] = 'total'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ix` to set multiple columns at the same time without problem:

```
In [8]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5), 'b':np.random.randn(5), 'c':np.random.randn(5)})
df
Out[8]:
          a         b         c
0  0.623686  0.875752  1.027399
1 -0.806096  0.349891  0.290276
2  0.750623  0.704666 -1.401591
3 -0.594068 -1.148006  0.373021
4 -1.060019 -0.325563 -0.536769

In [9]:

df.ix[:,['a','b','c']] = 'total'
df
Out[9]:
       a      b      c
0  total  total  total
1  total  total  total
2  total  total  total
3  total  total  total
4  total  total  total
```

Answer (score 1):

Those look like [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) so have a read on the official documentation.

You can assign a single key some value. The key must be unique and hashable (that's why dicts work so fast and are basically the backbone of python). Lists are mutable objects and can't be hashed.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671376/hashable-immutable) or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671211/create-a-dictionary-in-python-which-is-indexed-by-lists) questions.