# Python: map list to a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need something like

```
list_dict_dict = {
    [] : {}
}
```

the problem is [] isnt hashable and cannot be used as a dictionary key

any data structure out there i can used to map a list to a dict?

Comment: Google your title.

Comment: "I need something like" Why?

Comment: @Constantinius each item in the list requires info in the dict

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671211/create-a-dictionary-in-python-which-is-indexed-by-lists

Comment: @MarounMaroun not showing what i want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the list to a tuple

```
my_dict = {}
my_tuple = tuple(my_list)
my_dict[my_tuple] = my_value
```

However, afterwards if you make any changes in the list, those will not be reflected in the tuple that you used as the key. List cannot be used as a dict key because it can be mutated, which will change its hash each time an object is added or removed.