# How to "perfectly" override a dict?

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary, get, set

How can I make as "perfect" a subclass of *dict* as possible? The end goal is to have a simple *dict* in which the keys are lowercase.

It would seem that there should be some tiny set of primitives I can override to make this work, but according to all my research and attempts it seem like this isn't the case:

- If I [override `__getitem__`/`__setitem__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390889), then `get`/`set` don't work.    How can I make them work?  Surely I don't need to implement them individually?
- Am I preventing pickling from working, and do I need to implement `__setstate__` etc?
- Do I [need `repr`, `update` and `__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390997)?
- Should I just [use mutablemapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622872) (it seems one shouldn't use `UserDict`
  or `DictMixin`)?  If so, how? The docs aren't exactly enlightening.

Here is my first go at it, `get()` doesn't work and no doubt there are many other minor problems:

```
class arbitrary_dict(dict):
    """A dictionary that applies an arbitrary key-altering function
       before accessing the keys."""

    def __keytransform__(self, key):
        return key

    # Overridden methods. List from 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    # Note: I'm using dict directly, since super(dict, self) doesn't work.
    # I'm not sure why, perhaps dict is not a new-style class.

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, self.__keytransform__(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return dict.__setitem__(self, self.__keytransform__(key), value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__delitem__(self, self.__keytransform__(key))

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return dict.__contains__(self, self.__keytransform__(key))


class lcdict(arbitrary_dict):
    def __keytransform__(self, key):
        return str(key).lower()
```

Comment: I think __keytransform__() should be static. Nice approach though.
(prepending @staticmethod)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1392396

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You can write an object that behaves like a `dict` quite easily with [ABC](https://docs.python.org/library/abc.html)s (Abstract Base Classes) from the [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) module.  It even tells you if you missed a method, so below is the minimal version that shuts the ABC up.

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping


class TransformedDict(MutableMapping):
    """A dictionary that applies an arbitrary key-altering
       function before accessing the keys"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.store = dict()
        self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs))  # use the free update to set keys

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.store[self._keytransform(key)]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.store[self._keytransform(key)] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.store[self._keytransform(key)]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.store)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.store)

    def _keytransform(self, key):
        return key
```

You get a few free methods from the ABC:

```
class MyTransformedDict(TransformedDict):

    def _keytransform(self, key):
        return key.lower()


s = MyTransformedDict([('Test', 'test')])

assert s.get('TEST') is s['test']   # free get
assert 'TeSt' in s                  # free __contains__
                                    # free setdefault, __eq__, and so on

import pickle
# works too since we just use a normal dict
assert pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(s)) == s
```

I wouldn't subclass `dict` (or other builtins) directly. It often makes no sense, because what you actually want to do is *implement the interface of a `dict`*. And that is exactly what ABCs are for.

Comment: Question though--won't implementing this interface with a user-defined type generally result in slower dict-like operations that using the built-in type?

Comment: @twneale yes, but that probably doesn't matter to someone using Python.

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that isinstance(_, dict) == True ? Or do you just use Mutable Mapping to construct then subclass?

Comment: @NeilG Then what's the gain on this approach, other than 20 extra lines, over `MyClass = type('MyClass', (dict,), {})`?

Comment: @AndyHayden: You should write `if isinstance(t, collections.MutableMapping): print t, "can be used like a dict"`. Don't check the type of a object, check the interface.

Comment: @NeilG This unfortunately includes the JSONEncoder in the python standard library - https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/json/encoder.py#L308

Comment: Is it possible to implement `TransformedDict` like this with `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` aliases for get/setting `self.store`'s contents? (i.e. `obj.key = val` behaves just like `obj['key'] = val`.) I keep running into either `RecursionError`s or `AttributeError`s.

Comment: (Please see [implementing-a-dict-like-object-with-getattr-and-setattr-functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081356/implementing-a-dict-like-object-with-getattr-and-setattr-functionality/) where I answer my own question.)

Comment: Why use this \_\_keytransform\_\_ method when you could just use the arg, key directly?

Comment: @JamesT., the keytransform method is meant to be overloaded by a derived class, as in the "MyTransformedDict" example.

Comment: Jochen: Your advice to @AndyHayden is fine for your own code, but that cannot always be done when it's not. For example, the `json` module explicitly checks `isinstance(obj, dict)`.

Comment: Why not just use `self.store = dict(*args, **kwargs)` in the initializer?

Comment: The unpacking operator `*` in `dict(*args, **kwargs)` is wrong. `dict()`'s constructor only accepts 1 positional arg. It accepts multiple kwargs though. As a result `__init__()` of `TransformedDict` is wrong too. It should be `__init__(self, seq=None, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Since this question is 13yrs old, is this still the preferred solution in 2023 and Python 3.12 era, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 137):

> ## How can I make as "perfect" a subclass of dict as possible?
>
> The end goal is to have a simple dict in which the keys are lowercase.
>
> - If I override `__getitem__`/`__setitem__`, then get/set don't work. How
>     do I make them work? Surely I don't need to implement them
>     individually?
> - Am I preventing pickling from working, and do I need to implement
>     `__setstate__` etc?
> - Do I need repr, update and `__init__`?
> - Should I just use `mutablemapping` (it seems one shouldn't use `UserDict`
>     or `DictMixin`)? If so, how? The docs aren't exactly enlightening.

The accepted answer would be my first approach, but since it has some issues,
and since no one has addressed the alternative, actually subclassing a `dict`, I'm going to do that here.

### What's wrong with the accepted answer?

This seems like a rather simple request to me:

> How can I make as "perfect" a subclass of dict as possible? 
>   The end goal is to have a simple dict in which the keys are lowercase.

The accepted answer doesn't actually subclass `dict`, and a test for this fails:

```
>>> isinstance(MyTransformedDict([('Test', 'test')]), dict)
False
```

Ideally, any type-checking code would be testing for the interface we expect, or an abstract base class, but if our data objects are being passed into functions that are testing for `dict` - and we can't "fix" those functions, this code will fail.

Other quibbles one might make:

- The accepted answer is also missing the classmethod: `fromkeys`.
- The accepted answer also has a redundant `__dict__` - therefore taking up more space in memory:

  ```
  >>> s.foo = 'bar'
  >>> s.__dict__
  {'foo': 'bar', 'store': {'test': 'test'}}
  ```

### Actually subclassing `dict`

We can reuse the dict methods through inheritance. All we need to do is create an interface layer that ensures keys are passed into the dict in lowercase form if they are strings.

> If I override `__getitem__`/`__setitem__`, then get/set don't work. How do I make them work? Surely I don't need to implement them individually?

Well, implementing them each individually is the downside to this approach and the upside to using `MutableMapping` (see the accepted answer), but it's really not that much more work.

First, let's factor out the difference between Python 2 and 3, create a singleton (`_RaiseKeyError`) to make sure we know if we actually get an argument to `dict.pop`, and create a function to ensure our string keys are lowercase:

```
from itertools import chain
try:              # Python 2
    str_base = basestring
    items = 'iteritems'
except NameError: # Python 3
    str_base = str, bytes, bytearray
    items = 'items'

_RaiseKeyError = object() # singleton for no-default behavior

def ensure_lower(maybe_str):
    """dict keys can be any hashable object - only call lower if str"""
    return maybe_str.lower() if isinstance(maybe_str, str_base) else maybe_str
```

Now we implement - I'm using `super` with the full arguments so that this code works for Python 2 and 3:

```
class LowerDict(dict):  # dicts take a mapping or iterable as their optional first argument
    __slots__ = () # no __dict__ - that would be redundant
    @staticmethod # because this doesn't make sense as a global function.
    def _process_args(mapping=(), **kwargs):
        if hasattr(mapping, items):
            mapping = getattr(mapping, items)()
        return ((ensure_lower(k), v) for k, v in chain(mapping, getattr(kwargs, items)()))
    def __init__(self, mapping=(), **kwargs):
        super(LowerDict, self).__init__(self._process_args(mapping, **kwargs))
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return super(LowerDict, self).__getitem__(ensure_lower(k))
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        return super(LowerDict, self).__setitem__(ensure_lower(k), v)
    def __delitem__(self, k):
        return super(LowerDict, self).__delitem__(ensure_lower(k))
    def get(self, k, default=None):
        return super(LowerDict, self).get(ensure_lower(k), default)
    def setdefault(self, k, default=None):
        return super(LowerDict, self).setdefault(ensure_lower(k), default)
    def pop(self, k, v=_RaiseKeyError):
        if v is _RaiseKeyError:
            return super(LowerDict, self).pop(ensure_lower(k))
        return super(LowerDict, self).pop(ensure_lower(k), v)
    def update(self, mapping=(), **kwargs):
        super(LowerDict, self).update(self._process_args(mapping, **kwargs))
    def __contains__(self, k):
        return super(LowerDict, self).__contains__(ensure_lower(k))
    def copy(self): # don't delegate w/ super - dict.copy() -> dict :(
        return type(self)(self)
    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, keys, v=None):
        return super(LowerDict, cls).fromkeys((ensure_lower(k) for k in keys), v)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0}({1})'.format(type(self).__name__, super(LowerDict, self).__repr__())
```

We use an almost boiler-plate approach for any method or special method that references a key, but otherwise, by inheritance, we get methods: `len`, `clear`, `items`, `keys`, `popitem`, and `values` for free. While this required some careful thought to get right, it is trivial to see that this works.

(Note that `haskey` was deprecated in Python 2, removed in Python 3.)

Here's some usage:

```
>>> ld = LowerDict(dict(foo='bar'))
>>> ld['FOO']
'bar'
>>> ld['foo']
'bar'
>>> ld.pop('FoO')
'bar'
>>> ld.setdefault('Foo')
>>> ld
{'foo': None}
>>> ld.get('Bar')
>>> ld.setdefault('Bar')
>>> ld
{'bar': None, 'foo': None}
>>> ld.popitem()
('bar', None)
```

> Am I preventing pickling from working, and do I need to implement
>   `__setstate__` etc?

### pickling

And the dict subclass pickles just fine:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(ld)
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nLowerDict\nq\x00)\x81q\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00fooq\x02Ns.'
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(ld))
{'foo': None}
>>> type(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(ld)))
<class '__main__.LowerDict'>
```

### `__repr__`

> Do I need repr, update and `__init__`?

We defined `update` and `__init__`, but you have a beautiful `__repr__` by default:

```
>>> ld # without __repr__ defined for the class, we get this
{'foo': None}
```

However, it's good to write a `__repr__` to improve the debugability of your code. The ideal test is `eval(repr(obj)) == obj`. If it's easy to do for your code, I strongly recommend it:

```
>>> ld = LowerDict({})
>>> eval(repr(ld)) == ld
True
>>> ld = LowerDict(dict(a=1, b=2, c=3))
>>> eval(repr(ld)) == ld
True
```

You see, it's exactly what we need to recreate an equivalent object - this is something that might show up in our logs or in backtraces:

```
>>> ld
LowerDict({'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2})
```

### Conclusion

> Should I just use `mutablemapping` (it seems one shouldn't use `UserDict`
>   or `DictMixin`)? If so, how? The docs aren't exactly enlightening.

Yeah, these are a few more lines of code, but they're intended to be comprehensive. My first inclination would be to use the accepted answer, 
and if there were issues with it, I'd then look at my answer - as it's a little more complicated, and there's no ABC to help me get my interface right.

Premature optimization is going for greater complexity in search of performance.
`MutableMapping` is simpler - so it gets an immediate edge, all else being equal. Nevertheless, to lay out all the differences, let's compare and contrast.

I should add that there was a push to put a similar dictionary into the `collections` module, but [it was rejected](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2015-May/140003.html). You should probably just do this instead:

```
my_dict[transform(key)]
```

It should be far more easily debugable.

#### Compare and contrast

There are 6 interface functions implemented with the `MutableMapping` (which is missing `fromkeys`) and 11 with the `dict` subclass. I don't need to implement `__iter__` or `__len__`, but instead I have to implement `get`, `setdefault`, `pop`, `update`, `copy`, `__contains__`, and `fromkeys` - but these are fairly trivial, since I can use inheritance for most of those implementations.

The `MutableMapping` implements some things in Python that `dict` implements in C - so I would expect a `dict` subclass to be more performant in some cases.

We get a free `__eq__` in both approaches - both of which assume equality only if another dict is all lowercase - but again, I think the `dict` subclass will compare more quickly.

#### Summary:

- subclassing `MutableMapping` is simpler with fewer opportunities for bugs, but slower, takes more memory (see redundant dict), and fails `isinstance(x, dict)`
- subclassing `dict` is faster, uses less memory, and passes `isinstance(x, dict)`, but it has greater complexity to implement.

Which is more perfect? That depends on your definition of perfect.

Comment: How would the accepted answer remove the redundant dict?

Comment: Two ways that immediately come to mind are to either declare the store attribute in `__slots__` or perhaps reuse the `__dict__` as the store, but that mixes semantics, another potential point of criticism.

Comment: Would'nt it have been easier to write a decorator that takes a method and uses your `ensure_lower` on the first arguemtn (which is always the key)? Then it would be the same number of overrides, but they would all be of the form `__getitem__ = ensure_lower_decorator(super(LowerDict, self).__getitem__)`.

Comment: @Graipher that won't work - self, passed to super, is an argument to the method. You could possibly do it by hard-coding the parent's `__getitem__` but since that's less correct, I don't think it's "easier". Although if you think I'm wrong, feel free to write a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for this - getting warnings for pop and fromkeys that they do not match the signature of base class method.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D  Thanks for the feedback - I gave it a little more finessing. Let me know how it works for you now, I want it to be as complete as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot - will try and use it and get back with more feedback (don't hold your breath :P)  - for now I think that to shutdown the warnings (PyCharm) `fromKeys` should be a class method`@staticmethod def fromkeys(keys, v=None):` and call `return super(LowerDict, LowerDict).fromkeys((ensure_lower(k) for k in keys), v)` - btw Pycharm warns for passing a generator in `fromkeys((ensure_lower(k)...` but that can be safely ignored I guess

Comment: And another gotcha - copy - `ld = LowerDict(dict(foo='bar')) ; ld = ld.copy(); ld['FOO']` -> KeyError

Comment: And a final point to consider: would it be worth it to replace the `if hasattr(mapping, items):` with a `isinstance(mpping, collections.abc.Mapping)` ? Which are the pros and cons ? Anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I added an implementation of `copy` - I think that should do it, no? I think it should test for the interface - e.g. the pandas DataFrame object is not a Mapping instance (at last check) but it does have items/iteritems.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against subclassing dict, at least in Python 2.7.   Take your example, and `**an_instance` it - you'll see that it doesn't call any of your methods, and this is a fairly common thing to do in Python.  In your specific example this doesn't matter, since it's storing already-lowered keys in the backing dict (which is what ** will access), but in general this isn't necessarily true.

Comment: @Groxx give us some code that demonstrates your objections

Comment: Just did!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47361653/16295 and https://repl.it/repls/TraumaticToughCockatoo

Comment: I wonder if this code can be abstracted so you pass a MutableMapping and it returns a subclass of dict with the MutableMapping used for methods.

Answer (score 7):

After trying out both of the [top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387975/16295) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375731/16295) suggestions, I've settled on a shady-looking middle route for Python 2.7.  Maybe 3 is saner, but for me:

```
class MyDict(MutableMapping):
   # ... the few __methods__ that mutablemapping requires
   # and then this monstrosity
   @property
   def __class__(self):
       return dict
```

which I really hate, but seems to fit my needs, which are:

- can override `**my_dict`

  - if you inherit from `dict`, *this bypasses your code*.  try it out.
  - this makes [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375731/16295) unacceptable for me *at all times*, as this is quite common in python code
- masquerades as `isinstance(my_dict, dict)`

  - rules out MutableMapping alone, so [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387975/16295) is not enough
  - I heartily recommend [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387975/16295) if you don't need this, it's simple and predictable
- fully controllable behavior

  - so I cannot inherit from `dict`

If you need to tell yourself apart from others, personally I use something like this (though I'd recommend better names):

```
def __am_i_me(self):
  return True

@classmethod
def __is_it_me(cls, other):
  try:
    return other.__am_i_me()
  except Exception:
    return False
```

As long as you only need to recognize yourself internally, this way it's harder to accidentally call `__am_i_me` due to python's name-munging (this is renamed to `_MyDict__am_i_me` from anything calling outside this class).  Slightly more private than `_method`s, both in practice and culturally.

So far I have no complaints, aside from the seriously-shady-looking `__class__` override.  I'd be *thrilled* to hear of any problems that others encounter with this though, I don't fully understand the consequences.  But so far I've had no problems whatsoever, and this allowed me to migrate a lot of middling-quality code in lots of locations without needing any changes.

---

As evidence: https://repl.it/repls/TraumaticToughCockatoo

Basically: copy [the current #2 option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375731/16295), add `print 'method_name'` lines to every method, and then try this and watch the output:

```
d = LowerDict()  # prints "init", or whatever your print statement said
print '------'
splatted = dict(**d)  # note that there are no prints here
```

You'll see similar behavior for other scenarios.  Say your fake-`dict` is a wrapper around some other datatype, so there's no reasonable way to store the data in the backing-dict; `**your_dict` will be empty, regardless of what every other method does.

This works correctly for `MutableMapping`, but as soon as you inherit from `dict` it becomes uncontrollable.

---

Edit: as an update, this has been running without a single issue for almost two years now, on several hundred thousand (eh, might be a couple million) lines of complicated, legacy-ridden python.  So I'm pretty happy with it :)

Edit 2: apparently I mis-copied this or something long ago.  `@classmethod __class__` does not work for `isinstance` checks - `@property __class__` does: https://repl.it/repls/UnitedScientificSequence

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"`**your_dict` will be empty"* (if you subclass from `dict`)? I have not seen any problems with dict unpacking...

Comment: If you actually put data into the parent dict (like LowerDict does), it works - you'll get that dict-stored data.  If you *don't* (say you wanted to generate data on the fly, like {access_count: "stack trace of access"} that fills in each time it's read), you'll notice that `**your_dict` doesn't execute your code, so it can't output anything "special".  E.g. you can't count "reads" because it doesn't execute your read-counting code.  MutableMapping *does* work for this (use it if you can!), but it fails `isinstance(..., dict)` so I couldn't use it.  yay legacy software.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. I suppose I didn't expect code execution with `**your_dict`, but I find it very interesting that `MutableMapping` will do that.

Comment: Yea.  It's necessary for a number of things (e.g. I was shimming RPC calls into what used to be a local-dict read, and had to do it on demand for Reasons™), and it seems very few people are aware of it, even tho `**some_dict` is fairly common.  At the very least it happens very often in decorators, so if you have *any*, you're immediately at risk of seemingly-impossible misbehavior if you don't account for it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but the `def __class__()` trick doesn't seem to work with either Python 2 or 3, at least for the example code in the question [How to register implementation of abc.MutableMapping as a dict subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982946/how-to-register-implementation-of-abc-mutablemapping-as-a-dict-subclass) (modified to otherwise work in the two versions). I want `isinstance(SpreadSheet(), dict)` to return `True`.

Comment: Hmm, may have found a way to get it to work: If I also add a `self.__class__ = dict` to my class' `__init__()` method, then `isinstance(_, dict)` _will_ return `True`. The `def __class__()` is still needed, because without it, the assignment raises `TypeError: __class__ assignment only supported for heap types or ModuleType subclasses`.

Comment: @martineau: With the `self.__class__` assignment in place, the only role of your `__class__` classmethod is to hide the normal `__class__` descriptor. Anything that actually uses the classmethod will probably fail, because the classmethod makes no sense. `__class__` isn't supposed to behave as any sort of method.

Comment: In particular, this answer's use of a `__class__` classmethod doesn't make `isinstance` checks work like Groxx thinks, so either that giant legacy codebase isn't *really* relying on those isinstance checks passing, or something else is going on.

Comment: I must've made a wrong copy/paste somewhere.  Yep, `@classmethod __class__` doesn't work.  `@property __class__` does.  (I have a test suite that ensures this does work, not sure why I got it wrong here). Evidence: https://repl.it/repls/UnitedScientificSequence

Comment: In any case tho: thanks for being suspicious!  It got me to look more closely and write some small tests, and then wonder wtf I did that worked previously (or if something changed between python 2.7.10 and 2.7.16).  Yay old code that still runs.

Answer (score 6):

My requirements were a bit stricter:

- I had to retain case info (the strings are paths to files displayed to the user, but it's a windows app so internally all operations must be case insensitive)
- I needed keys to be as small as possible (it *did* make a difference in memory performance, chopped off 110 mb out of 370). This meant that caching lowercase version of keys is not an option.
- I needed creation of the data structures to be as fast as possible (again made a difference in performance, speed this time). I had to go with a builtin

My initial thought was to substitute our clunky Path class for a case insensitive unicode subclass - but:

- proved hard to get that right - see: [A case insensitive string class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43122096/281545)
- turns out that explicit dict keys handling makes code verbose and messy - and error prone (structures are passed hither and thither, and it is not clear if they have CIStr instances as keys/elements, easy to forget plus `some_dict[CIstr(path)]` is ugly)

So I had finally to write down that case insensitive dict. Thanks to [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375731/281545) by @AaronHall that was made 10 times easier.

```
class CIstr(unicode):
    """See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43122305/281545, especially for inlines"""
    __slots__ = () # does make a difference in memory performance

    #--Hash/Compare
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.lower())
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, CIstr):
            return self.lower() == other.lower()
        return NotImplemented
    def __ne__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, CIstr):
            return self.lower() != other.lower()
        return NotImplemented
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, CIstr):
            return self.lower() < other.lower()
        return NotImplemented
    def __ge__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, CIstr):
            return self.lower() >= other.lower()
        return NotImplemented
    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, CIstr):
            return self.lower() > other.lower()
        return NotImplemented
    def __le__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, CIstr):
            return self.lower() <= other.lower()
        return NotImplemented
    #--repr
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0}({1})'.format(type(self).__name__,
                                 super(CIstr, self).__repr__())

def _ci_str(maybe_str):
    """dict keys can be any hashable object - only call CIstr if str"""
    return CIstr(maybe_str) if isinstance(maybe_str, basestring) else maybe_str

class LowerDict(dict):
    """Dictionary that transforms its keys to CIstr instances.
    Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39375731/281545
    """
    __slots__ = () # no __dict__ - that would be redundant

    @staticmethod # because this doesn't make sense as a global function.
    def _process_args(mapping=(), **kwargs):
        if hasattr(mapping, 'iteritems'):
            mapping = getattr(mapping, 'iteritems')()
        return ((_ci_str(k), v) for k, v in
                chain(mapping, getattr(kwargs, 'iteritems')()))
    def __init__(self, mapping=(), **kwargs):
        # dicts take a mapping or iterable as their optional first argument
        super(LowerDict, self).__init__(self._process_args(mapping, **kwargs))
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return super(LowerDict, self).__getitem__(_ci_str(k))
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        return super(LowerDict, self).__setitem__(_ci_str(k), v)
    def __delitem__(self, k):
        return super(LowerDict, self).__delitem__(_ci_str(k))
    def copy(self): # don't delegate w/ super - dict.copy() -> dict :(
        return type(self)(self)
    def get(self, k, default=None):
        return super(LowerDict, self).get(_ci_str(k), default)
    def setdefault(self, k, default=None):
        return super(LowerDict, self).setdefault(_ci_str(k), default)
    __no_default = object()
    def pop(self, k, v=__no_default):
        if v is LowerDict.__no_default:
            # super will raise KeyError if no default and key does not exist
            return super(LowerDict, self).pop(_ci_str(k))
        return super(LowerDict, self).pop(_ci_str(k), v)
    def update(self, mapping=(), **kwargs):
        super(LowerDict, self).update(self._process_args(mapping, **kwargs))
    def __contains__(self, k):
        return super(LowerDict, self).__contains__(_ci_str(k))
    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, keys, v=None):
        return super(LowerDict, cls).fromkeys((_ci_str(k) for k in keys), v)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0}({1})'.format(type(self).__name__,
                                 super(LowerDict, self).__repr__())
```

Implicit vs explicit is still a problem, but once dust settles, renaming of attributes/variables to start with ci (and a big fat doc comment explaining that ci stands for case insensitive) I think is a perfect solution - as readers of the code must be fully aware that we are dealing with case insensitive underlying data structures.
This will hopefully fix some hard to reproduce bugs, which I suspect boil down to case sensitivity.

Comments/corrections welcome :)

Comment: CIstr's `__repr__` should use the parent class's `__repr__` to pass the eval(repr(obj)) == obj test (I don't think it does right now) and not rely on `__str__`.

Comment: Also check out the [`total_ordering` class decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) - that will eliminate 4 methods from your unicode subclass. But the dict subclass looks very cleverly implemented. :P

Comment: Thanks @AaronHall - it's you who implemented that :P Re: total ordering - I intentionally wrote the methods inlined as advised by Raymond Hettinger here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43122305/281545. Re: repr: I remember reading a comment (by some core dev IIRC) that well, it's not really worth the hassle to try and make repr to pass that test (it's a hassle) - better focus on it being as informative as possible (but not more)

Comment: I'll allow you your redundant comparison methods (you should make a note about it in your answer), but the `CIstr.__repr__`, in *your* case, can pass the repr test with very little hassle, and it should make debugging a lot nicer. I'd also add a `__repr__` for your dict. I'll do it in my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @AaronHall: I added `__slots__` in CIstr - does make a difference in performance (CIstr is not meant to be subclassed or indeed used outside LowerDict, should be a static nested final class). Still not sure how to solve elegantly the repr issue (the sting might contain a combination of `'` and `"` quotes)

Comment: delegate to the builtin `__repr__` with `super` - both classes should do that - `__slots__` make sense for `CIstr` - no `__dict__` needed - subclasses of `CIstr` won't care because `__slots__` are empty..

Comment: Relevant: [PEP 455](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/) and [the rejection.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2015-May/140003.html)

Answer (score 6):

All you will have to do is

```
class BatchCollection(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

OR

```
class BatchCollection(dict):
    def __init__(self, inpt={}):
        super(BatchCollection, self).__init__(inpt)
```

A sample usage for my personal use

```
### EXAMPLE
class BatchCollection(dict):
    def __init__(self, inpt={}):
        dict.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if (isinstance(key, tuple) and len(key) == 2
                and isinstance(item, collections.Iterable)):
            # self.__dict__[key] = item
            super(BatchCollection, self).__setitem__(key, item)
        else:
            raise Exception(
                "Valid key should be a tuple (database_name, table_name) "
                "and value should be iterable")
```

**Note**: tested only in python3

Comment: None of this works for me: the first variant of `__init__` gives the error "TypeError: descriptor '\_\_init__' of 'dict' object needs an argument". If I try the other version of `__init__` and override `__setitem__` as you have done I get "AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_BatchCollection__set__item'", not suprisingly: method name mangling has kicked in. I can't understand how this can have been upvoted 6 times.

Answer (score 3):

`collections.UserDict` is often the simplest option when you need a custom `dict`.

As shown in the other answer, it's very tricky to overwrite `dict` correctly, while `UserDict` makes it easy. To answer the original question, you can get a dict with lower keys:

```py
import collections

class LowercaseDict(collections.UserDict):

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return super().__getitem__(key.lower())

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    return super().__setitem__(key.lower(), value)

  def __delitem__(self, key):
    return super().__delitem__(key.lower())

  # Unfortunately, __contains__ is required currently due to
  # https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91784
  def __contains__(self, key):
    return key.lower() in self.data


d = LowercaseDict(MY_KEY=0)  # Keys normalized in .__init__
d.update({'OTHER_KEY': 1})  # Keys normalized in .update
d['Hello'] = d['other_KEY']
assert 'HELLO' in d
print(d)  # All keys normalized {'my_key': 0, 'other_key': 1, 'hello': 1}
```

And contrary to `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, you don't need `__iter__`, `__len__`, `__init__`,...
Subclassing `UserDict` is much easier.

However `UserDict` is a `MutableMapping`, not a `dict`, so:

```py
assert not isinstance(collections.UserDict(), dict)
assert isinstance(collections.UserDict(), collections.abc.MutableMapping)
```

Comment: `json.dumps(d) >>> TypeError: Object of type LowercaseDict is not JSON serializable`

Comment: I believe that with the current Python version (2023), the first goto when subclassing dictionaries should be to subclass UserDict. That is, as the first goto - there might be reason for other choices in some cases.