# What's wrong with superclass.method(object, parms)?

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, super

Say I have this sample code I'm writing for a Python lesson I'm holding:

```
class Enum(dict):
  def __init__(self, *values):
    values = {mnemo: num
      for num, mnemo in enumerate(values)}
    dict.__init__(self, values) # ← this
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return self[name]
```

This seems to work as expected, at least on a shallow method, but what I see most of the time on  the literature on the Internet is:

- Avoid inheriting from inbuilt types: [it's much better to type out proxy methods by hand!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/python-how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict)
- Using `super().method` rather than explicitly naming `superclass.method`

I guess especially the latter is more DRY, but super() is going to be trickier to explain once I start throwing in multiple inheritance. I want to make sure, then, that there are no nasty gotchas in there that other people will then stumble upon.

Comment: If you introduce super, do it properly. One cannot use it well without understanding the concept of the MRO. See [Python's super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: @delnan I was actually considering not introducing it at all :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I don't see why you should generally avoid to derive from built-in types.  It was considered an improvement that the arrival of new-style classes enabled to do this, and even before this the standard library provided the `UserDict` and `UserList` classes to derive from.  Of course you have to evaluate in every specific case whether inheritance or composition is what you need, but that's how in always is in OOP -- nothing special about built-in types here.
2. I wouldn't recommend `super()` in the example.  It is only useful if all cooperating methods have the same signature, or at least cooperating signatures.  For single inheritance and "diamond-free" multiple inheritance, explicitly calling base-class methods is fine in my opinion.  If you want to get things right in multiple inheritance with diamonds, you are forced to use `super()`, but you have to design your methods carefully, see [Raymond Hettinger's "Python's `super()` considered super!"](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

   It is generally safe to use `super()` in cases where all involved methods have exactly the same signature, including methods likes `__getattr__()` and `__setattr__()`.
3. Your example class is a rather questionable implementation of an `Enum` type, but not for any of the reasons you mentioned in your post.  It mixes up two namespaces:  The namespace of the attributes of `dict` and the enumeration entries.  Try `Enum("clear", "update")` to see what I mean.  In this particular case, the follwing implementation would be much better:

   ```
   class Enum(object):
       def __init__(self, *values):
           vars(self).update({mnemo: num for num, mnemo in enumerate(values)})
   ```

   This adds the enumeration entries as attributes to a standard instance without deriving from `dict`.  Every custom class instance brings its own dictionary anyway, namely `__dict__`.

Comment: Re: 1. There's no guarantee overriden methods are called by builtin non-overriden methods. For instance, if you inherit from `dict` and override `__getitem__` but not `get`, the latter may bypass your override for the former.