# Why doesn't **kwargs interpolate with python ConfigObj?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, configobj

I'm using [ConfigObj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html) in python with Template-style interpolation. Unwrapping my config dictionary via ** doesn't seem to do interpolation.  Is this a feature or a bug?  Any nice workarounds?

```
$ cat my.conf
foo = /test
bar = $foo/directory

>>> import configobj
>>> config = configobj.ConfigObj('my.conf', interpolation='Template')
>>> config['bar']
'/test/directory'
>>> '{bar}'.format(**config)
'$foo/directory'
```

I'd expect the second line to be `/test/directory`.  Why doesn't interpolation work with **kwargs?

Comment: The `**` keyword argument unpacking only works for mappings.  Most probably, `ConfigObj` instances are not exposing the full [mapping](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-mapping) interface.

Comment: ConfigObj *inherits* from dict, so it definitely provides the full mapping interface (and infact the ** unpack has *worked* it has just got the wrong values). I'm not sure how "**"" gets values out, it is obviously bypassing the interpolation though. I'll have to do some experimentation to work out.

Comment: Isn't there some weirdness associated with inheriting directly from dict? e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/python-how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict. I'm no expert on this, but perhaps using the [MutableMapping](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping) or [DictMixin](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html#UserDict.DictMixin) would be better?

Comment: Yes, inheriting from dict and overriding access methods tends to be a bit fragile, as none of the "extra" functionality (such as the update method) will respect your overridden methods. I would guess the python interpreter is doing the `**kwargs` unpacking directly against the C level implementation of `dict`, since this is one. Unlike `update` et al, I'm not sure this could even be fixed by overriding more methods. :(

Comment: So essentially there is no way to override the ** operator for the `dict` class. Bummer.  I guess the solution is to inherit from `UserDict` or implement all of `MutableMapping`, but not inherit from `dict` which will probably be much slower (pure python functions vs C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When unpacking the keyword argument, then a new object is created: of type `dict`. This dictionary contains the the raw-values of the configuration (no interpolation)

Demonstration:

```
>>> id(config)
31143152
>>> def showKeywordArgs(**kwargs):
...     print(kwargs, type(kwargs), id(kwargs))
...
>>> showKeywordArgs(**config)
({'foo': '/test', 'bar': '$foo/directory'}, <type 'dict'>, 35738944)
```

To resolve your problem you could create an expanded version of your configuration like this:

```
>>> expandedConfig = {k: config[k] for k in config}
>>> '{bar}'.format(**expandedConfig)
'/test/directory'
```

Another more elegant way is to simply avoid unpacking: This can be achieved by using the function [string.Formatter.vformat](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.Formatter.vformat):

```
import string
fmt = string.Formatter()
fmt.vformat("{bar}", None, config)
```

Comment: Since my ConfigObj doesn't change over the course of the script, this will be fine.  It sure seems clunky though!

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem.

A workaround is to use configobj's function ".dict()". This works because configobj returns a real dictionary, which Python knows how to unpack.

Your example becomes:

```
>>> import configobj
>>> config = configobj.ConfigObj('my.conf', interpolation='Template')
>>> config['bar']
'/test/directory'
>>> '{bar}'.format(**config.dict())
'/test/directory'
```