# How to allow for extra characters in dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {
           hey: onevalue,
           hat: twovalue,
           how: threevalue
           }
```

Is there any way to account for a reference to a key while having a variable, say a number in it?

such as my_dict['hey1'] = onevalue
or my_dict['hey2'] = onevalue

I'm trying to allow for such a variable instead of stripping the numbers from the reference to the key. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you want to get `onevalue` when you have the key `hey1` or `hey2`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do here. Ignore the digits at the end for both getting and setting?

Comment: That would be a yes to both. I want to be able to add a digit to the key and have it return the same value regardless of what's after the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not. Due to how dicts work (as a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)), they have no way to accommodate what you want. You will have to create your own type and define the [`__*item__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) methods to implement your logic.

Comment: Based on where I'm at with python, it would be less frustrating and more educational just to strip the trailing characters before referencing the key. Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387975/477878), you can define your own dict compatible type to strip trailing digits;

```
import collections

class TransformedDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    """A dictionary which applies an arbitrary key-altering function before accessing the keys"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.store = dict()
        self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs)) # use the free update to set keys

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.store[self.__keytransform__(key)]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.store[self.__keytransform__(key)] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.store[self.__keytransform__(key)]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.store)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.store)

    def __keytransform__(self, key):
        for i in xrange(len(key)-1,-1,-1):
          if not key[i].isdigit():
            break
        return key[:i]

a = TransformedDict()
a['hello'] = 5
print a['hello123']

>>> 5
```