# Override a dict with numpy support

Tags: python, numpy, inheritance, dictionary

Using the base idea from [How to "perfectly" override a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/python-how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict), I coded a class based on dictionaries that should support assigning dot delimited keys, i.e. `Extendeddict('level1.level2', 'value') == {'level1':{'level2':'value'}}`

The code is

```
import collections
import numpy

class Extendeddict(collections.MutableMapping):
    """Dictionary overload class that adds functions to support chained keys, e.g. A.B.C          
    :rtype : Extendeddict
    """
    # noinspection PyMissingConstructor
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._store = dict()
        self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        keys = self._keytransform(key)
        print 'Original key: {0}\nTransformed keys: {1}'.format(key, keys)
        if len(keys) == 1:
            return self._store[key]
        else:
            key1 = '.'.join(keys[1:])
            if keys[0] in self._store:
                subdict = Extendeddict(self[keys[0]] or {})
                try:
                    return subdict[key1]
                except:
                    raise KeyError(key)
            else:
                raise KeyError(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        keys = self._keytransform(key)
        if len(keys) == 1:
            self._store[key] = value
        else:
            key1 = '.'.join(keys[1:])
            subdict = Extendeddict(self.get(keys[0]) or {})
            subdict.update({key1: value})
            self._store[keys[0]] = subdict._store

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        keys = self._keytransform(key)
        if len(keys) == 1:
            del self._store[key]
        else:
            key1 = '.'.join(keys[1:])
            del self._store[keys[0]][key1]
            if not self._store[keys[0]]:
                del self._store[keys[0]]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._store)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._store)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._store.__repr__()

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def _keytransform(self, key):
        try:
            return key.split('.')
        except:
            return [key]
```

But with Python 2.7.10 and numpy 1.11.0, running

```
basic = {'Test.field': 'test'}
print 'Normal dictionary: {0}'.format(basic)
print 'Normal dictionary in a list: {0}'.format([basic])
print 'Normal dictionary in numpy array: {0}'.format(numpy.array([basic], dtype=object))
print 'Normal dictionary in numpy array.tolist(): {0}'.format(numpy.array([basic], dtype=object).tolist())

extended_dict = Extendeddict(basic)
print 'Extended dictionary: {0}'.format(extended_dict)
print 'Extended dictionary in a list: {0}'.format([extended_dict])
print 'Extended dictionary in numpy array: {0}'.format(numpy.array([extended_dict], dtype=object))
print 'Extended dictionary in numpy array.tolist(): {0}'.format(numpy.array([extended_dict], dtype=object).tolist())
```

I get:

```
Normal dictionary: {'Test.field': 'test'}
Normal dictionary in a list: [{'Test.field': 'test'}]
Normal dictionary in numpy array: [{'Test.field': 'test'}]
Normal dictionary in numpy array.tolist(): [{'Test.field': 'test'}]
Original key: Test
Transformed keys: ['Test']
Extended dictionary: {'Test': {'field': 'test'}}
Extended dictionary in a list: [{'Test': {'field': 'test'}}]
Original key: 0
Transformed keys: [0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/scratch_2.py", line 77, in <module>
    print 'Extended dictionary in numpy array: {0}'.format(numpy.array([extended_dict], dtype=object))
  File "/tmp/scratch_2.py", line 20, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key]
KeyError: 0
```

Whereas I would expect `print 'Extended dictionary in numpy array: {0}'.format(numpy.array([extended_dict], dtype=object))` to result in `Extended dictionary in numpy array: [{'Test': {'field': 'test'}}]`

Any suggestions on what might be wrong for this? Is this even the right way to do it?

Comment: it seems to me that you're trying to reinvent the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) library ;)

Comment: @MaxU Pandas does something quite different from what I would need for this, and I do use it for many other things. What I want is a "simple" class dictionary-like that support s dot-delimited fields.

Comment: Add some debugging prints, for exaple `key` and `keys` near the error.

Comment: I would use `pdb` to check what is going wrong.

Comment: What happens with the object in a list? Or the `thearrary.tolist()`.  If I ran your code I'd be trying all sorts of prints and actions, trying to find a pattern.

Comment: @hpaulj I added the prints and tried checking the behaviour in a list, but as you can see it's not very elucidative. The main issue is that for some reason the `numpy.array()` is trying to access key `0` of the object, which obviously does not exist.

Comment: @rocksportrocker Thanks for the suggestions. I will try to see if it helps figuring out the issue.

Comment: With added prints at the start of `__getitem__` I see that the problem is with `key=0`.  Looks like the array display is trying to iterate through the object as if it were a list or array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `np.array` constructor step.  It digs into its inputs trying to create a higher dimensional array.

```
In [99]: basic={'test.field':'test'}

In [100]: eb=Extendeddict(basic)

In [104]: eba=np.array([eb],object)
<keys: 0,[0]>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-5591a58c168a> in <module>()
----> 1 eba=np.array([eb],object)

<ipython-input-88-a7d937b1c8fd> in __getitem__(self, key)
     11         keys = self._keytransform(key);print key;print keys
     12         if len(keys) == 1:
---> 13             return self._store[key]
     14         else:
     15             key1 = '.'.join(keys[1:])

KeyError: 0
```

But if I make an array, and assign the object it works fine

```
In [105]: eba=np.zeros((1,),object)

In [106]: eba[0]=eb

In [107]: eba
Out[107]: array([{'test': {'field': 'test'}}], dtype=object)
```

`np.array` is a tricky function to use with `dtype=object`.  Compare `np.array([[1,2],[2,3]],dtype=object)` and `np.array([[1,2],[2]],dtype=object)`.  One is (2,2) the other (2,).  It tries to make a 2d array, and resorts to 1d with list elements only if that fails.  Something along that line is happening here.

I see 2 solutions - one is this round about way of constructing the array, which I've used in other occasions.  The other is to figure out why `np.array` doesn't dig into `dict` but does with yours.  `np.array` is compiled, so that may require reading tough GITHUB code.

---

I tried a solution with  `f=np.frompyfunc(lambda x:x,1,1)`, but that doesn't work (see my edit history for details). But I found that mixing an `Extendeddict` with a `dict` does work:

```
In [139]: np.array([eb,basic])
Out[139]: array([{'test': {'field': 'test'}}, {'test.field': 'test'}], dtype=object)
```

So does mixing it with something else like `None` or an empty list

```
In [140]: np.array([eb,[]])
Out[140]: array([{'test': {'field': 'test'}}, []], dtype=object)

In [142]: np.array([eb,None])[:-1]
Out[142]: array([{'test': {'field': 'test'}}], dtype=object)
```

This is another common trick for constructing an object array of lists.

It also works if you give it two or more `Extendeddict` with different lengths

`np.array([eb, Extendeddict({})])`.  In other words if `len(...)` differ (just as with mixed lists).

Comment: Unfortunately, the same happens if I remove the `dtype` argument. :(

Comment: The issue isn't the `dtype=object`.  I think it analyses the input before even looking at the `dtype`.  From its behavior I think only looks at the `dtype` near the end, when actually constructing the result.

Comment: I did try the same things as you did, adding a different length object, which works as you describe. But this also means that everyone using this library would need to be aware of this issue, which seems counter-productive to me.
I'll keep it as is for now, but I'll upvote your answer in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy tries to do what it's supposed to do:

Numpy checks for each element if it's iterable (by using `len` and `iter`) because what you pass in may be interpreted as a multidimensional array.

There is a catch here: `dict`-like classes (meaning `isinstance(element, dict) == True`) will not be interpreted as another dimension (that is why passing in `[{}]` works). Probably they should check if it's a `collections.Mapping` instead of a `dict`. Maybe you can file a bug on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues).

If you change your class definition to:

```
class Extendeddict(collections.MutableMapping, dict):
     ...
```

**or** change your `__len__`-method:

```
    def __len__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

it works. Neither of these might be something that you want to do but numpy just uses *duck typing* to create the array and without subclassing directly from `dict` or by making `len` inaccessible numpy sees your class as something that ought to be another dimension. This is rather clever and convenient in case you want to pass in customized sequences (subclasses from `collections.Sequence`) but inconvenient for `collections.Mapping` or `collections.MutableMapping`. I think this a **Bug**.

Comment: I did try to inherit from `dict`, but that causes a bunch of other issues that I couldn't figure out how to solve properly,
But yeah, I also think it might be a bug in numpy itself.

Comment: @NicolauGonçalves I didn't want to recommend inheriting from `dict`. It was just to illustrate why I came to the conclusion.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to the other answer, not defining length would be rather counter-productive if anyone would use this class.
But I will create an issue in numpy and see what the developers think.