# Creating a numpy array fails when I try to create from an array of QString

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt4

If the array has a size of 2x2 or greater all is well, but if the dimension of the row is 1, for example 1x2, numpy does something I did not expect.

How can I solve this?

```
# TEST 1 OK
myarray = np.array([[QString('hello'), QString('world')],
                    [QString('hello'), QString('moon')]],
                   dtype=object)
print myarray
print myarray.shape
#[[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'hello') PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'world')]
# [PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'hello') PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'moon')]]
#(2, 2)


# TEST 2 OK
myarray = np.array([['hello'], ['world']], dtype=object)
print myarray
print myarray.shape  
#[['hello']
# ['world']]
#(2, 1)


# TEST 3 FAIL
myarray = np.array([[QString('hello'), QString('world')]], dtype=object)
print myarray
print myarray.shape
#[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'h')]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
#..
#[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'e')]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
# etc...
#(1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Oh weird... Almost seems like numpy is treating the strings as arrays or something... What happens if you put a comma between the 2 closing square brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try different length strings:

```
np.array([[QString('hello'), QString('moon')]], dtype=object)`.
```

or the create and fill approach to making an object array

```
A = np.empty((1,2), dtype=object)
A[:] = [QString('hello'), QString('moon')]
```

I'm not familiar with these objects, but in other cases where we try to build object arrays from lists, it is tricky if the lists are the same length.  If `QString` is iterable, with a `.__len__` something similar may be happening.

I'm guessing your first example works because on `QString` is shorter than the others, not because it is 2x2.

This recent question about making an object array from a custom dictionary class may be relevant: [Override a dict with numpy support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663919/override-a-dict-with-numpy-support)

Comment: It is true, I tried the first example and fails if the lengths are identicals!. Good link, maybe the cause of the problem it's related with http://stackoverflow.com/a/36666424/2270217 , but I think that your solution for me it's enough Thank you!