# Randomly select item from list of lists gives ValueError

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, nested-lists

I have a function that sometimes gives me a list of lists where the nested lists sometimes only have one item, such as this one:

```
a = [['1'], ['3'], ['w']]
```

And want to randomly select one item from that main list `a`. If I try to use `np.random.choice` on this list, I get a `ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional`.

But if the list were instead:

```
b = [['1'], ['3'], ['w', 'w']]
```

Then using `np.random.choice` works perfectly fine. Why is this? And how can I make it so that I can randomly select from both types of lists?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use just `random.choice`. You don't need **numpy** for everything.

Answer (score 3):

I think `choice` is first turning your list into an array.

In the second case, this array is a 1d array with dtype object:

```
In [125]: np.array([['1'], ['3'], ['w', 'w']])
Out[125]: array([['1'], ['3'], ['w', 'w']], dtype=object)
In [126]: _.shape
Out[126]: (3,)
```

In the second, it makes a 2d array of strings:

```
In [127]: np.array([['1'], ['3'], ['w']])
Out[127]: 
array([['1'],
       ['3'],
       ['w']], 
      dtype='<U1')
In [128]: _.shape
Out[128]: (3, 1)
```

This is an issue that comes up periodically.  `np.array` tries to create as a high a dimensional array as the input allows.

[Prevent numpy from creating a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774922/prevent-numpy-from-creating-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: No need to just "think" it; you can find the code in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx, where you'll find that the first thing `choice` does is `a = np.array(a, copy=False)`.

Comment: Now I'm off to discard the answer I was editing.  hpaulj is just too fast. :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "how to make it work" part you can use:

```
np.random.choice(np.squeeze(a))
```

Note that this will eliminate the square brackets for `a`, but not for `b`. But might still be useful.