# Returning an numpy array of array based on a list of parameters

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a very simple code to compute the vertical movement. I have set some initial conditions (in this case  `v0s`). Instead to run a for loop over each one of the `v0s`, is that any way to "apply" each `v0` to the `x linspace` and have a **array of numpy arrays**.

```
import numpy as np

v0s = [1, 2, 3]
g = 9.81

def VerticalPosition(v0,g,t):
    return(v0*t - 0.5 * g * t**2)

def Solution(v0,g):
    return(2*v0/g)

def Apex(v0,g):
    return(VerticalPosition(v0,g,v0/g))

x=np.linspace(0,Solution(max(v0s),g),101)

y=[]
for v0 in v0s:
    y.append(VerticalPosition(v0,g,x))
```

Comment: `frompyfunc` is probably what you want to try here

Comment: `array of arrays` is ambiguous.  Do you mean a 2d numpy array (of floats)?  Or a 1d object array with array elements?  `VerticalPosition` works with broadcastable arrays.  Going the object array route is trickier and slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @pekapa's answer (which returns a 2d array of floats) is what most would recommend, here is a method that produces an array of arrays.

```
y = np.frompyfunc(lambda a, b: VerticalPosition(a, b, x), 2, 1)(v0s, g)
```

Arrays of arrays are useful when the inner arrays have different shapes. (Not the case in the present example).

Re the use of `x` in the above expression. It is taken from the enclosing (not necessarily global) scope but that can with a bit of care be managed. The easiest is to just pack it in a function and make it explicit. Since the inner functions are evaluated immedately and then discarded `x` being mutable poses no problem here.

```
def capsule(v0s, g, x):
    return np.frompyfunc(lambda a, b: VerticalPosition(a, b, x), 2, 1)(v0s, g)
```

Here is an example that essentially only works with an array of arrays:

```
a,b = np.ogrid[1:4, 5:9:2]
np.frompyfunc(np.arange, 2, 1)(a, b)
# array([[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])],
#        [array([2, 3, 4]), array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])],
#        [array([3, 4]), array([3, 4, 5, 6])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: But you had to treat `x` as a global.  You couldn't pass it through the `frompyfunc` because it would try to broadcast it against `v0s`, and produce an object array of float values.  Here I don't think it offers much of an advantage over the original list iteration.  Usually a list of arrays is better than an array of arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Agreed. I think the only advantage -- if you really want an array of arrays -- is that it makes it comparatively easy to control the depth of the new array. Actually, I have been wondering since there is an `ndmin` kw in the array constructor; why is there no `ndmax`? Do you happen to know? Should I make an SO question of that? Found it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774922/prevent-numpy-from-creating-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: Indeed, my example doesn't show any need of array of arrays, since my second level array has equal dimensions (that could not be the case), but in fact this needs X as global and that I have to avoid (trying to go functional in some point in future).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use all vectors, and, in your case, that's quite simple.

Try having v0s as a vector with:

```
v0s = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
```

note that it's a 3x1 vector, `v0s.shape` should be `(3, 1)`

Your `x linspace` is already a vector `x.shape` is `(101,)`

Now you can just multiply them. Or, call `VerticalPosition` straight with your new `v0s` vector, i.e.

```
y = VerticalPosition(v0s, g, x)
```

Comment: Tachnically, that doesn't yield an array of arrays as OP asked for.

Comment: Actually, it does. A python matrix is nothing more than an array of arrays. You can even check by printing the results where it states: `array([[ ... ], [ ... ], [ ... ]])`

Comment: In case you want to understand the difference between a 2d array of scalars and a 1d array of 1d arrays of scalars: Look at this simple example [[1,2],[3,4,5]]. Not representable as an array of scalars without destroying its structure. Perfectly straightforward to represent as an array of arrays.

Comment: `np.split` or even `list(y)` can be used to create a list of arrays.