# Prevent TypedDict from accepting arbitrary parameters

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing, typeddict

I noticed that `TypedDict` seems to let you pass any arguments to it which is not great.

```
class X(TypedDict):
    id: int

obj1 = X(id=4)
print(obj1)
# {'obj1': 1}

obj2 = X(id=4, thing=3)
print(obj2)
# {'obj1': 1, 'thing': 3} # bad!
```

I guess this is since TypedDict only works at the type checker level.

But if I still wanted to prevent this happening during runtime, what is the alternative to using a TypedDict?

Comment: You may be interested in [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) or [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type safety in current versions of Python is not achieved at runtime, but through the use of a static ahead-of-execution analysis with [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/)

This is true also for [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), which have a similar scope as [`TypedDict`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/), with the difference that dataclasses will check for undefined attributes, but it would not really behave like a `dict`. This would be true for [NamedTuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) too (except that the object is immutable).

If you want to enforce type safety at runtime, this must be done explicitly, e.g.:

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, *, bar):
       if isinstance(bar, int):
           self.bar = bar
       else:
           raise TypeError

Foo(bar=1)
# <__main__.Foo at 0x7f5400f5c730>

Foo(bar="1")
# TypeError

Foo(baz=1)
# TypeError
```

or defining a class that would be closer to a TypedDict, but with runtime type checking, you could do something like:

```
class RuntimeTypedDict(dict):       
    def __init__(self, **kws):
        unseen = set(self.__annotations__.keys())
        for key, value in kws.items():
            # invalid key/value type checks replicated here for performance
            if key in self.__annotations__:
                if isinstance(value, self.__annotations__[key]):
                    unseen.remove(key)
                else:
                    raise TypeError("Invalid value type.")
            else:
                raise TypeError("Invalid key.")
        if unseen != set():
            raise TypeError("Missing required key.")
        super(RuntimeTypedDict, self).__init__(**kws)
        
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.__annotations__:
            if isinstance(value, self.__annotations__[key]):
                super(RuntimeTypedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
            else:
                raise TypeError("Invalid value type.")
        else:
            raise TypeError("Invalid key.")
```

which can be used similarly to TypedDict:

```
class MyDict(RuntimeTypedDict):
    # __annotations__ = {"x": int}  # use this on older Python versions
    x: int


d = MyDict(x=1)
print(d)
# {'x': 1}

d["x"] = 2
print(d)
# {'x': 2}

d["x"] = 1.1
# TypeError: Invalid value type.
d["y"] = 1
# TypeError: Invalid key.

d = MyDict(x=1.1)
# TypeError: Invalid value type.

d = MyDict(x=1, y=1)
# TypeError: Invalid key.

d = MyDict()
# TypeError: Missing required key.
```

or similar.

**EDITED** to include a runtime type checking dynamic class that is easy to subclass.

Comment: It's probably better to use the ``__annotations__`` for allowed types, instead of introducing another protocol for specifying types.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That was actually a good suggestion, because then one could use the standard Python annotation syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this doesn't provide type-checking in `dict.update`, because `dict.update` doesn't actually call `dict.__setitem__`. It might be wiser to use `collections.UserDict` as a base class, rather than subclassing `dict`; you'd need to override fewer methods. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362420/subclassing-dict-dict-update-returns-incorrrect-value-python-bug

Comment: Certainly `collections.UserDict` is an option. Not sure it's necessarily better than `dict` itself in this case. I'd not consider writing a few more lines of code an issue. I'd be more worried about performances for example.

Answer (score 1):

Both [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) provide key checking on construction. Using your examples:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import NamedTuple

@dataclass
class X1:
    id: int

class X2(NamedTuple):
    id: int

X1(id=4) # ok
X2(id=4) # ok

X1(id=4, thing=3)
# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

X2(id=4, thing=3)
# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

Do note that dataclasses do not prevent you from assigning to "bad" attributes after construction. The following code is still valid:

```
x1 = X1(id=4)
x1.thing = 3  # still ok
```

In contrast, named tuples are immutable, so assigning to arbitrary attributes at runtime isn't possible:

```
x2 = X2(id=4)
x2.thing = 3
# AttributeError: 'X2' object has no attribute 'thing'
```

Comment: A ``dataclass`` can be created with ``__slots__``, which prevents additional attributes.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to use **mypy** package.

```
sudo pip3.9 install mypy
rehash
```

```
cat typedDict_ex.py
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
from typing import TypedDict
class X(TypedDict):
    id: int

obj1 = X(id=4)
print(obj1)
# {'obj1': 1}

obj2 = X(id=4, thing=3)
print(obj2)
# {'obj1': 1, 'thing': 3} # bad!
```

```
mypy typedDict_ex.py
typedDict_ex.py:10: error: Extra key "thing" for TypedDict "X"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: The question is specifically about a runtime implementation.