# Dictionary subclass, are all editing methods covered with callback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I wanted to have a function that handled a dictionary, addressed like a dictionary or similar with little work, so that when called I could run other code.

I thought it seemed easier to subclass dict, so I have. From reading `help(dict)` I think I have covered all dictionary editing functions so that a callback is called too. Have I? Also are there any other like pop which return a value of the editing ones?

```
class BindedDict(dict):
    """Custom dictionary with callback when edited."""

    def __init__(self, callback, *a, **kw):
        self.callback = callback
        super().__init__(*a, *kw)
        return

    def __delitem__(self, *a, **kw):
        super().__delitme__(*a, **kw)
        self.callback()
        return

    def __setitem__(self, *a, **kw):
        super().__setitem__(*a, **kw)
        self.callback()
        return

    def clear(self, *a, **kw):
        super().clear(*a, **kw)
        self.callback()
        return

    def pop(self, *a, **kw):
        r = super().pop(*a, **kw)
        self.callback()
        return r

    def popitem(self, *a, **kw):
        super().popitem(*a, **kw)
        self.callback()
        return

    def setdefault(self, *a, **kw):
        super().setdefault(*a, **kw)
        self.callback()
        return

    def update(self, *a, **kw):
        super().update(*a, **kw)
        self.callback()
        return
```

Also a better title and class name would be good.

Comment: `__delitme__`? I'd recommend looking into the `MutableMapping` [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.htmlhttps://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). If your code works correctly, and you want improvements suggested, see [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe . I had not tested deleting yet and thats a typo. By the way the ABC link is dead.

Comment: @Peilonrayz managed to paste it twice... https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe looking at the docs it does not explain much there, I'm going to google it but if you see this: what and how could I use it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd use composition rather than inheritance, and implement the `MutableMapping` from [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) so that I get some of the methods implemented for free. Per the documentation, you have to provide implementations of `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__`:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping


class BoundDict(MutableMapping):
    """Dict-like class that calls a callback on changes.

    Note that the callback is invoked *after* the 
    underlying dictionary has been mutated.

    """

    def __init__(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        self._callback = callback
        self._map = dict(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._map[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._map[key] = value
        self._callback()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._map[key]
        self._callback()

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._map)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._map)
```

Note that you don't need to put a bare `return` at the end of a method, and I've added a docstring to explain what the class does.

Thanks to the abstract base class, the following additional methods will now be implemented for you: `__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `get`, `__eq__`, and `__ne__`, `pop`, `popitem`, `clear`, `update`, and `setdefault`. Because they all call through to the five fundamental methods defined above, it's guaranteed that any change through the `MutableMapping` interface (although *not* changes to `_map` directly) will invoke the callback, as it will always involve calling either `__setitem__` or `__delitem__`.

In use:

```
>>> bd = BoundDict(lambda: print('changed'), [('foo', 'bar')], hello='world')
>>> bd
<BoundDict object at 0x7f8a4ea61048>
>>> list(bd.items())
[('foo', 'bar'), ('hello', 'world')]
>>> bd['foo']
'bar'
>>> bd['hello']
'world'
>>> bd['foo'] = 'baz'
changed
>>> del bd['hello']
changed
>>> bd['foo']
'baz'
>>> bd['hello']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "python", line 16, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'hello'
```

The only downside to this is that if you have explicit type checking, you might have issues:

```
>>> isinstance(bd, dict)
False
```

However, you should generally be using the ABCs for your type checks, too (or just [duck typing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-duck-typing)):

```
>>> isinstance(bd, MutableMapping)
True
>>> isinstance(dict(), MutableMapping)
True
```

---

I think when you ask *"and that explains why I only see one callback with my example?"* [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478363/dictionary-subclass-are-all-editing-methods-covered-with-callback/44478584#comment75952727_44478584) you want to know why the following happens with our different implementations:

```
>>> BindedDict(lambda: print('changed'), foo='bar', hello='world').clear()
changed
>>> BoundDict(lambda: print('changed'), foo='bar', hello='world').clear()
changed
changed
```

This is due to the implementation of [`MutableMapping.clear`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L816); it loops over the keys in the dictionary, calls `popitem` for each one, which in turn calls `__delitem__`, which in turns calls the callback. By contrast, your implementation calls the callback only once, because you implement `clear` directly and call it from there.

Note that the ABC approach **doesn't prevent you from doing this**. It's not clear from your question (and you may not yet *know*) which is the correct behaviour, but you *can* still come in and override the default implementations provided by the ABC:

```
class BoundDict(MutableMapping):
    """..."""

    ...

    def clear(self):
        self._map.clear()  # or e.g. self._map = {}
        self._callback()
```

The reason I recommend using the ABC rather than subclassing `dict` is that this gives you sensible default implementations that you can override where you need to, so you only need to worry about where your behaviour *differs* from the defaults. Fewer methods implemented also means a smaller risk of simple typos like `__delitme__` (if you don't provide a required `@abstractmethod` you get an error when you try to instantiate the class) and `super().__init__(*a, *kw)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good explanation. What I don't get is why people are saying on different questions at when you subclass dict you don't get the methods? As everything is working from what I tested and it does not have downsides to ABC MM. Another thing, with your example above you say that you only need call back on `__setitem__` and `__delitem__`. Do the other methods use internal methods then to access them as with my code the callback is only called once as if the main two are not called? I might add a logger to each one to see...

Comment: *"why people are saying on different questions at when you subclass dict you don't get the methods?"* - I don't understand the question, if you have other information maybe provide links? *"Do the other methods use internal methods then to access them"* - as I say in the answer, the extra methods that are implemented for you all call through to the five required implementations. Do `bd = BoundDict(lambda: print('changed'), [('foo', 'bar')], hello='world')` then `bd.clear()` and you'll see `changed` twice, for example.

Comment: So when you inherit a class you get all its methods, so what methods would I be missing? In your example: `methods implemented for free`, [Another Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict) Do you, and they mean I do not have to cover all methods which I want to change as it does not use super() which then called the parents unchanged methods and that explains why I only see one callback with my example?

Comment: @Max sorry, I've no idea what you're trying to ask now. It's not clear why you think you're missing *any* methods - **the ABC provides them for you**. This approach doesn't have inheritance or `super`. It's unclear what your example is.

Comment: @Max I think I figured out what you meant by the last part at least and have edited my answer. It's worth having a look at the source code I link to, in the context of [how ABCs work generally in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#module-abc); the `MutableMapping` and `Mapping` are pretty straightforward.