# Pickle a dict subclass without __reduce__ method does not load member attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, inheritance, pickle

I have the need to ensure that a `dict` can only accept a certain type of objects as values.  It also have to be pickable.
Here is my first attempt:

```py
import pickle

class TypedDict(dict):
    _dict_type = None

    def __init__(self, dict_type, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._dict_type = dict_type

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self._dict_type):
            raise TypeError('Wrong type')
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

If I test it with the following code (python 3.5)

```py
my_dict = TypedDict(int)
my_dict['foo'] = 98

with open('out.pkl', 'wb') as fin:
    pickle.dump(my_dict, fin)

with open('out.pkl', 'rb') as fin:
    out = pickle.load(fin)
```

I get the error: `TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`. 
It seems that it is not loading the correct value for `_dict_type` and it is instead using the default `None`. 
Also, It seems to be dependent on the protocol as if it is working correctly with `protocol=0`

However, if I override the `__reduce__` method and just call the super everything magically works.

```py
def __reduce__(self):
    return super().__reduce__()
```

How it is possible? Shouldn't be the two classes (w/o `__reduce__`) equivalent? What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "perfectly" override a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict)

Comment: @eugecm I don't think that the linked question answers my question about why adding a nop `__reduce__` makes everything work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How it is possible? Shouldn't be the two classes (w/o `__reduce__`) equivalent? What am I missing?

You're missing a crucial step: If there is no `__reduce__` method (or if it fails!) it will use other means to pickle your class. So a class with `__reduce__` won't behave like a class without `__reduce__` (there are several special methods that behave like that)!

In your first case it will default to basic `dict` dumping and loading and then handling the subclasses logic. So it will create the dictionary using several `__setitem__` calls and then set the instance attributes. But your `__setitem__` requires the **instance attribute** `_dict_type`. If it doesn't have one it will default to the **class attribute** `None`, which fails with the

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

That's why it works if you want to pickle your `TypedDict` without `__reduce__` if it doesn't contain any key-value pairs. Because it won't call `__setitem__` and afterwards sets the instance attribute:

```
my_dict = TypedDict(int)

with open('out.pkl', 'wb') as fin:
    pickle.dump(my_dict, fin)

with open('out.pkl', 'rb') as fin:
    out = pickle.load(fin)

print(out._dict_type)   # int
```

On the other hand it works if you implement your `__reduce__` method because unlike normal dicts which fail with `__reduce__` - it does work for subclasses (but it's not attempted if you don't implement `__reduce__`):

```
>>> d = {1: 1}
>>> dict.__reduce__(d)
TypeError: "can't pickle dict objects"

>>> d = TypedDict(int)
>>> dict.__reduce__(d)
(<function copyreg._reconstructor>,
 (__main__.TypedDict, dict, {}),
 {'_dict_type': int})
```