# Python - Transform class attributes at call time

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, getattr, class-attributes

Suppose I have the following class

```
class Headings:
    standard_heading = {
        'height': 3.72,
        'width': 25.68,
        'left': 1.65,
        'top': 0.28
    }
```

As an example, I want the following results where all values have been multiplied by 10:

```
Headings.standard_heading

>>> {
            'height': 37.2,
            'width': 256.8,
            'left': 16.5,
            'top': 2.8
        }
```

Is there no way to override the calling of a class attribute by adding a method similar to this to the class:

```
def __getattribute__(cls, attr):
    return {k:v*10 for k,v in attr.items()
```

I won't ever be creating instances of this class. I just use it for grouping purposes.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `@property` decorator: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17330160/4121573

Comment: What is the point of storing the original values if you always get 10 times them when you ask for them?

Comment: That's not the actual implementation I'm going for. Just used it for ease of explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it - just define it the getter as a class method (also you had a small syntax error, `attr` is a string here):

```
class Headings:
    standard_heading = {
        'height': 3.72,
        'width': 25.68,
        'left': 1.65,
        'top': 0.28
    }          
    @classmethod
    def __getattribute__(cls,attr):
        return {k:v*10 for k,v in cls.__dict__[attr].items()}

print(Headings().standard_heading)
```

Note you do need an actual instance for this to work, but that's what you use in your example. This will also ruin get attribute for object specific fields defined within any method of the object (such as `__init__`), so careful with this. An easy fix is to override also:

```
@classmethod
def __getattribute__(cls,attr):
    try:
        return {k:v*10 for k,v in cls.__dict__[attr].items()}
    except: raise AttributeError(attr)
def __getattr__(self,attr):
    return object.__getattribute__(self,attr)
```

So now if you have:

```
def __init__(self): self.a = 'abc'
```

then

```
print(Headings().a)
```

will also work. Explanation:

1. First `__getattribute__` is called as a class method.
2. If no class variable exists, then `__getattr__` is invoked, now as a regular method, so with the actual object (and object members).
3. Call the `object` `__getattribute__` to fall back to normal behavior.

Last note - other than your specific question, if you just want to define a special `getter` for one class member, a safer way that will only affect said member is using `@property` and `@getter` -as explained for example in [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17330160/6881240). Thanks [Adonis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4121573/adonis) for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a parent class if you want to apply this behavior to many different classes.

```
class MultiplyBy10:
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        return {k:v*10 for k,v in super().__getattribute__(attr).items()}

class Headings(MultiplyBy10):
    standard_heading = {
        'height': 3.72,
        'width': 25.68,
        'left': 1.65,
        'top': 0.28
    }

h = Headings()
print(h.standard_heading)
```

will display

```
{'height': 37.2, 'width': 256.8, 'left': 16.5, 'top': 2.8000000000000003}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to change the value returned from your dictionary, short of creating another dictionary, you may want to build a custom one - :[How to "perfectly" override a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict)