# Python change namespace to access attributes of a class

Tags: python

I have a class with a lot of attributes to be set. In order to do so, I do:

```
opts.a = 1
opts.b = 2
  # ...
opts.xyz = 0
```

After repeatedly writing `opts.` at the beginning of variables I am wondering: **Is it possible to wrap this into a function or context so that the namespace is set to the class attributes** so that I don't have to write `opts` all the time? I.e. that I only have to do something like:

```
with opts:
   a = 1
   b = 2
     # ...
   xyz = 3
```

I thought of moving the code inside a function of the class, but that doesn't make things easier to read or write, since then I'd need to write `self` instead of `opts` everytime.

One side condition for my case: the `__setattr__` of the class should be called, since I did override that with a custom function to store the order in which attributes are set.

Comment: You can define a context manager to do that, but it is bad design.

Comment: If you have too many attributes, you might have a design issue rather perhaps a dict/list is more adapted?

Comment: I don't get it. Why are `a`, `b`, ... not set in `__init__`? If you allow default arguments there, you won't have to supply all the attributes to the contructor.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist no, I want `__setattr__` to be called. it stores the attr key in an ordered list so that I can call attributes in the order they were stored

Comment: @Adonis: Hm, maybe... I admit I am new to Python. I'm using the class as a "struct" in C, which was recommended somewhere on SO and worked fine so far `class opts: a = 1; b = 2  [ ... ]  pass` and access via `opts.a`. However, now I want to store the order in which they are set, which is why I override `__setattr__` to keep a list of keys when they are set. But then I need to call `opts.a = 1` so that `__setattr__` is executed.

Comment: @Honeybear Maybe you should consider abandoning the class-as-enum approach in favour of an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @BoarGules: Ye, I guess that is the way to go and what I'm asking here is probably not pythonic. I just like the `.key`-access much better than the `['key']`-access, but you can't have everything.

Comment: will delete this question after some time

Comment: Actually based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387975/4121573) you just have to add in the `__setitem__` call `setattr(self,key,value)` and you should have a dict, and the possibility to call `my_transformed_dict.key`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I take your question and the comments together, you want to use the *class-as-enum* approach, but with mutable values, you want a quick way to update multiple attributes, and you want to store the order in which the attributes are set.

Here is a partial implementation that does what I think you want:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__['values'] = collections.OrderedDict()
    def __setattr__ (self,a,v):
        self.__dict__['values'][a]=v
    def __getattr__ (self,a):
        return self.__dict__['values'][a]
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__['values'])
```

Given this definition you can do:

```
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.z = 56
>>> m.y = 22
>>> m.b = 34
>>> m.c = 12
>>> m
OrderedDict([('z', 56), ('y', 22), ('b', 34), ('c', 12)])
```

Quick update:

```
>>> m.values.update(f=2, g=3, h=5)
>>> m
OrderedDict([('z', 56), ('y', 22), ('b', 34), ('c', 12), ('h', 5), ('g', 3), ('f', 2)])
```

It is true that the relative order of `f`-`g` is a bit surprising, but since the update happens in a single statement, there is an argument for saying that the updates are simultaneous and so the relative order is arbitrary.