# Can I override what {} brackets do in python?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I've created a subclass of dict as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict). What I'd like to do is be able to create a new dictionary of my subclass by using bracket notation. Namely, when I have {"key":"value"}, I'd like it to call mydict(("key","value")). Is this possible?

Comment: No. And for good reasons: it would violate the expectations of people reading the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. And for good reasons: it would violate the expectations of people reading the code. It would also likely break any third-party libraries that you import which would (reasonably) expect dict literals to be standard python dictionaries.

A better method to fix this without lots of extra typing is to simply add a static `.from` method on your custom dictionary class that attempts to consume the literal and returns an instance of your custom dictionary.

```
MyDict.from({
  "key": "value"
})
```

Where an implementation of `from` might look something like

```
@classmethod
def from(cls, dictionary):
    new_inst = cls()
    for key, value of dictionary.items():
        new_inst[key] = value

    return newInst
```

### Edit based on comment:

user2357112 correctly points out that you could just use the constructor as long as the dict constructor's signature is the same as your custom class:

```
some_instance = MyDict({"key": "value"})
```

If you've messed with it though you'll have to go the custom route a la `from`.

Comment: For a dict subclass with the "usual" signature, that `from` method would be pointless; just using the constructor would do the same job. (For a dict subclass with a different signature, it's likely that such a `from` method wouldn't have enough information to construct an instance, because it's missing whatever information is in the normal constructor arguments.)

Comment: @user2357112 edited to include your point. However in the case where the signature is modified you'd just have to add the appropriate parameters to the definition of `from`.