# Is There a dict with User Provided Key Function in Python?

Tags: python

Some objects, numpy const arrays for example, are perfectly hashable but happened not to be (due to `__eq__` being repurposed as an arithmetic operator, in the numpy case). Some objects, numpy arrays again for example, have multiple defintions of equility (id-equility and value-equility). For those object, a `dict` with user provided key function (as in `sorted`) would be very useful.

My question is: Is there a `dict` with user provided key function, either builtin or implemented in few lines, in Python?

Comment: Do you just want to modify the default behaviour of the `keys()` method? Or do you men something else?

Comment: I would like a `key:Callable=None` argument in the dict constructor, which is then used for comparing keys, just like what `list.sort` or `sorted` does.

Comment: Maybe have a look at `collections.UserDict` which lets you construct classes tht behave like `dict`s?

Comment: I found a closely related question [How to “perfectly” override a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387691/4442250)