# Dealing with optional python dictionary fields

Tags: python, json, dictionary, attributeerror

I'm dealing with JSON data which I load into Python dictionaries. A lot of these have optional fields, which then may contain dictionaries, that kind of stuff.

```
dictionary1 = 
{"required": {"value1": "one", "value2": "two"},
"optional": {"value1": "one"}}

dictionary2 = 
{"required": {"value1": "one", "value2": "two"}}
```

If I do this,

```
dictionary1.get("required").get("value1")
```

this works, obviously, because the field `"required"` is always present.

However, when I use the same line on `dictionary2` (to get the optional field), this will produce an `AttributeError`

```
dictionary2.get("optional").get("value1")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

which makes sense, because the first `.get()` will return `None`, and the second `.get()` cannot call `.get()` on the None object.

I can solve this by giving default values in case the optional field is missing, but this will be annoying the more complex the data gets, so I'm calling this a "naive fix":

```
dictionary2.get("optional", {}).get("value1", " ")
```

So the first `.get()` will return an empty dictionary `{}`, on which the second `.get()` can be called, and since it obviously contains nothing, it will return the empty string, as defined per the second default.

This will no longer produce errors, but I was wondering if there is a better solution for this - especially for more complex cases (`value1` containing an array or another dictionary, etc....)

I could also fix this with try - except `AttributeError`, but this is not my preferred way either.

```
try:
    value1 = dictionary2.get("optional").get("value1")
except AttributeError:
    value1 = " "
```

I also don't like checking if optional field exists, this produces garbage code lines like

```
optional = dictionary2.get("optional")
if optional:
    value1 = optional.get("value1")
else:
    value1 = " "
```

which seems very non-Pythonic...

I was thinking maybe my approach of just chaining `.get()`s is wrong in the first place?

Comment: Why don't you like the try-except clause? It's the most pythonic way of approaching this and easiest to read.

Comment: just creates lines of code... I was looking for a one-liner I guess. (the code would be littered with try-except blocks)

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 thanks for sharing your solution, but typically that should be posted as an answer rather than an edit to the question. I removed it but feel free to post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you refer to `" "` as the empty string. This is incorrect; `""` is the empty string.

Second, if you're checking for membership, I don't see a reason to use the `get` method in the first place. I'd opt for something like the following.

```
if "optional" in dictionary2:
    value1 = dictionary2["optional"].get("value1")
else:
    value1 = ""
```

---

Another alternative to consider (since you're using the `get` method a lot) is to switch to the `defaultdict` class. For example,

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary2 = {"required": {"value1": "one", "value2": "two"}}
ddic2 = defaultdict(dict,dictionary2)
value1 = ddic2["optional"].get("value1")
```

Comment: correct on the empty string, my bad. checking if optional is in the dictionary first will  create a lot of extra lines of code. This becomes somewhat unmanageable the more checks there are...

Comment: @c See my edit: maybe it would be helpful to start using defaultdicts.

Comment: defaultdict seems great, can you explain why it doesnt work with .get("optional"), but only when I use ["optional"] ?

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 Yeah, defaultdict doesn't have a "get" method; the alternative that you get when the key is not present is automatically part of the `ddic2["optional"]` call

Comment: I'm actually going with this answer because the check for membership can be used as a ternary operator which bypasses the evaluation of the statement entirely, and can be turned into a slick one-liner, just like I was looking for     

`value1 = dictionary2["optional"]["value1"] if "optional" in dictionary2 else " "`

Comment: @c I didn’t realize you could use if/else that way, neat! Glad my answer was helpful

Answer (score 5):

In your code here:

```py
try:
    value1 = dictionary2.get("optional").get("value1")
except AttributeError:
    value1 = " "
```

You can use brackets and `except KeyError`:

```py
try:
    value1 = dictionary2["optional"]["value1"]
except KeyError:
    value1 = " "
```

If this is too verbose for the caller, add a helper:

```py
def get_or_default(d, *keys, default=None):
    try:
        for k in keys:
            d = d[k]
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return default
    return d

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {"a": {"b": {"c": [41, 42]}}}
    print(get_or_default(d, "a", "b", "c", 1)) # => 42
    print(get_or_default(d, "a", "b", "d", default=43)) # => 43
```

You could also subclass dict and use tuple bracket indexing, like NumPy and Pandas:

```py
class DeepDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, d, default=None):
        self.d = d
        self.default = default

    def __getitem__(self, keys):
        d = self.d
        try:
            for k in keys:
                d = d[k]
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            return self.default
        return d

    def __setitem__(self, keys, x):
        d = self.d
        for k in keys[:-1]:
            d = d[k]
        d[keys[-1]] = x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dd = DeepDict({"a": {"b": {"c": [42, 43]}}}, default="foo")
    print(dd["a", "b", "c", 1]) # => 43
    print(dd["a", "b", "c", 11]) # => "foo"
    dd["a", "b", "c", 1] = "banana"
    print(dd["a", "b", "c", 1]) # => "banana"
```

But there might be an engineering cost to this if it's confusing for other developers, and you'd want to flesh out the other expected methods as described in [How to "perfectly" override a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict) (consider this a proof-of-concept sketch). It's best not to be too clever.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`toolz.dicttoolz.get_in()`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.get_in) for this:

```
from toolz.dicttoolz import get_in

dictionary1 = {"required": {"value1": "one", "value2": "two"}, "optional": {"value1": "one"}}
dictionary2 = {"required": {"value1": "one", "value2": "two"}}

get_in(("optional", "value1"), dictionary1)
# 'one'

get_in(("optional", "value1"), dictionary2)
# None
```

If you don't want to install the whole library, you can just [copy the source](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/toolz/dicttoolz.html#get_in) licensed under BSD:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

def get_in(keys, coll, default=None, no_default=False):
    try:
        return reduce(operator.getitem, keys, coll)
    except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError):
        if no_default:
            raise
        return default
```

Comment: This seems very close to what I'm looking for! I'll consider using this library, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Since you like one-liners like <kbd>`dictionary2["optional"]["value1"] if "optional" in dictionary2 else " "`</kbd> and <kbd>`dictionary2.get("optional", {}).get("value1", " ")`</kbd>, I thought to also suggest</sup>

```py
getattr(dictionary2.get("optional"), "get", {}.get)("value1", " ")
```

By using **[`getattr`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/getattr)**, this also accounts for [and would return `" "` on] *`dictionary2['optional']`* not being a dictionary [instead of raising an `AttributeError` or `TypeError` with the other two methods].

If wrapped as a function, it would be something like

```py
# get_v2 = lambda d, k1, k2, vDef=None: getattr(d.get(k1), 'get', {}.get)(k2,vDef) ## OR
def get_v2(d, k1, k2, vDef=None): 
    return getattr(d.get(k1), 'get', {}.get)(k2,vDef)

a = get_v2(dictionary1, 'optional', 'value1', vDef=' ') ## -->  a='one'
b = get_v2(dictionary2, 'optional', 'value1', vDef=' ') ## -->  b=' '
```

---

However, if you want to be able to call it for any number of keys you'll need to used either **recursion**

```py
def getVal(obj, k1, *keys, vDef=None):
    nxtVal = getattr(obj, 'get', {}.get)(k1, vDef)
    return getVal(nxtVal, *keys, vDef=vDef) if keys else nxtVal
```

or **a loop**

```py
def getVal(obj, *keys, vDef=None):
    for k in keys: obj = getattr(obj, 'get', {}.get)(k, vDef)
    return obj
```

---

Although, I think it's more efficient to use **`try..except`** as already suggested by some.

```py
def getVal(obj, k1, *keys, vDef=None):
    try: return getVal(obj[k1], *keys, vDef=vDef) if keys else obj[k1]
    except: return vDef
```

or

```py
def getVal(obj, *keys, vDef=None):
    try: 
        for k in keys: obj = obj[k]
    except: obj = vDef
    return obj
```

---

You can also write a function that returns a function [ a bit like [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) ] and can be used like <kbd>`valGetter("optional", "value1")(dictionary2, " ")`</kbd>

```py
def valGetter(k1, *keys):
    if keys:
        def rFunc(obj, vDef=None):
            try: 
                for k in (k1,)+(keys): obj = obj[k]
            except: obj = vDef
            return obj
    else: 
        def rFunc(obj, vDef=None):
            try: return obj[k1]
            except: return vDef 
    return rFunc
```

but please note that this can turn out to be [rather slow compared to the other methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6kQx.png).

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way of going about it would be using the `try/except` block -

```
dictionary2 = {"required": {"value1": "one", "value2": "two"}}
try:
    value1 = dictionary2["optional"]["value1"]
except (KeyError, AttributeError) as e:
    value1 = ""
```

`KeyError` to capture the missing keys, and `AttributeError` to capture cases where you have a `list`/`str` instead of `dict` object.

---

If you don't like tons of `try/except` in your code, you can consider using a helper function -

```
def get_val(data, keys):
    try:
        for k in keys:
            data = data[k]
        return data
    except (KeyError, AttributeError) as e:
        return ""

dictionary2 = {"required": {"value1": "one", "value2": "two"}}
print(get_val(dictionary2, ("required", "value2")))
print(get_val(dictionary2, ("optional", "value1")))
```

outputs -

```
two
```

Comment: I will consider the idea of a helper function, but is there really no built-in way for this, something like dictionary2.get("optional").get("value1") or " ", which ignores the chained .get() and returns the "or" value in case the optional field is missing? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: In that case the best pythonic way would be to keep doing as one of your suggestions `dictionary2.get("optional", {}).get("value1", "")`

Answer (score 0):

I use reduce to achieve Javascript-like optional chaining in Python

```
from functools import reduce


data_dictionary = {
    'foo': {
        'bar': {
            'buzz': 'lightyear'
        },
        'baz': {
            'asd': 2023,
            'zxc': [
                {'patrick': 'star'},
                {'spongebob': 'squarepants'}
            ],
            'qwe': ['john', 'sarah']
        }
    },
    'hello': {
        'world': 'hello world',
    },
}


def optional_chaining_v1(dictionary={}, *property_list):
    def reduce_callback(current_result, current_dictionary):
        if current_result is None:
            return dictionary.get(current_dictionary)
        if type(current_result) != dict:
            return None
        return current_result.get(current_dictionary)
    return reduce(reduce_callback, property_list, None)


# or in one line
optional_chaining_v1 = lambda dictionary={}, *property_list: reduce(lambda current_result, current_dictionary: dictionary.get(current_dictionary) if current_result is None else None if type(current_result) != dict else current_result.get(current_dictionary), property_list, None)

# usage
optional_chaining_v1_result1 = optional_chaining_v1(data_dictionary, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz')
print('optional_chaining_v1_result1:', optional_chaining_v1_result1)
optional_chaining_v1_result2 = optional_chaining_v1(data_dictionary, 'foo', 'bar', 'buzz')
print('optional_chaining_v1_result2:', optional_chaining_v1_result2)

# optional_chaining_v1_result1: None
# optional_chaining_v1_result2: lightyear


def optional_chaining_v2(dictionary={}, list_of_property_string_separated_by_dot=''):
    property_list = list_of_property_string_separated_by_dot.split('.')

    def reduce_callback(current_result, current_dictionary):
        if current_result is None:
            return dictionary.get(current_dictionary)
        if type(current_result) != dict:
            return None
        return current_result.get(current_dictionary)
    return reduce(reduce_callback, property_list, None)


# or in one line
optional_chaining_v2 = lambda dictionary={}, list_of_property_string_separated_by_dot='': reduce(lambda current_result, current_dictionary: dictionary.get(current_dictionary) if current_result is None else None if type(current_result) != dict else current_result.get(current_dictionary), list_of_property_string_separated_by_dot.split('.'), None)

# usage
optional_chaining_v2_result1 = optional_chaining_v2(data_dictionary, 'foo.bar.baz')
print('optional_chaining_v2_result1:', optional_chaining_v2_result1)
optional_chaining_v2_result2 = optional_chaining_v2(data_dictionary, 'foo.bar.buzz')
print('optional_chaining_v2_result2:', optional_chaining_v2_result2)

# optional_chaining_v2_result1: None
# optional_chaining_v2_result2: lightyear
```