# Python's method like 'equals' in Java

Tags: python, equals

How could I make `set` to have objects equality depended on a custom attribute which I'd set? Like Java's `equals` method.

The point is that I want to have a set which contains tuples `(x,y)`. When I try to put `(x,y)` tuple into the set, the result would depends on `x`.

```
set.add((x,y))
- OK 
set.add((x,z))
- Can't add because there is already a touple which has x as a first value.
```

Comment: Why not define a custom class?

Comment: Especially since you would need to regardless.

Comment: If you want most of the `set` class' functionality but want to change a few methods, you could do `class myName(Set):` and then define your own functions `def add(self, item): ...`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622722/overriding-set-methods-in-python.

Comment: This looks like a dict where you can only write elements once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a `dict` instead of a `set` of `tuple`s:

```
d = {}
d[x] = y
d[x] = z
```

This will override the value `y` with `z` though, but it makes sure you only have one value at a time.

If you don't want the overriding to be possible, you can subclass `dict` to prevent it:

```
class HalfFrozenDict(dict):  # Name is a subject to change

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            raise KeyError("Key '{}' already exists!".format(key))
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def update(self, other):
        other = {key: other[key] for key in other if key not in self}
        super().update(other)
```

Currently it raises an error if you try to re-set an item:

```
>>> d = HalfFrozenDict()
>>> d[0] = 1
>>> d[0] = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    d[0] = 2
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 5, in __setitem__
    raise KeyError("Key: '{}' already exists!".format(key))
KeyError: "Key '0' already exists!"
```

Also, calling `d.update(other)` will just ignore the duplicate keys from the `other` dict.

Both of these behaviours are a subject to change: would you rather raise an error on "invalid" `update()` call? Would you prefer to ignore a re-setting of an item (I think error is better in this case)?