# Converting a list of dictionaries to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

super beginner at python here.

I'm trying to convert a list of dictionaries into a single dictionary.

So, something like this:

```
[ {'Name': 'JD', 'Number': 1}, 
  {'Name': 'Turk', 'Number': 2}, 
  {'Name': 'Carla', 'Number': 3}],
```

I'd like to change it into

```
{'Name': 'JD', 'Number': 1, 
 'Name': 'Turk', 'Number': 2, 
 'Name': 'Carla', 'Number': 3}
```

I've been trying this for a while and have looked at a bunch of answers here, but it isn't working.

Thank you!

Comment: short answer: you can't, without blowing up the majority of your data.  Keys are unique.

Comment: He can use the index as a key.

Comment: Your expected output is not possible as dictionary key are unique.

Comment: Dict use hashing to index on key So two keys can be with same values and dict keys are unique. I believe your present data-structure is correct. What algo/operation you need apply on this list of dict?

Comment: I just changed my code and used something else. It worked out! Thanks guys. Should I just delete this post or?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of dictionaries, in a dictionary - in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889385/list-of-dictionaries-in-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this. As roippi said, **Keys are unique**

Try this instead:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> new_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for d in li:
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_dict[k].append(v)

>>> new_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Number': [1, 2, 3], 'Name': ['JD', 'Turk', 'Carla']})
```