# More nest Python nested dictionaries

Tags: python, collections, nested

After reading [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python) why is it wrong to do:

```
c = collections.defaultdict(collections.defaultdict(int))
```

in python? I would think this would work to produce

```
{key:{key:1}}
```

or am I thinking about it wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The constructor of `defaultdict` expects a callable. `defaultdict(int)` is a default dictionary object, not a callable. Using a `lambda` it can work, however:

```
c = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
```

This works since what I pass to the outer `defaultdict` is a callable that creates a new `defaultdict` when called.

Here's an example:

```
>>> import collections
>>> c = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
>>> c[5][6] += 1
>>> c[5][6]
1
>>> c[0][0]
0
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Eli Bendersky provides a great direct answer for this question. It might also be better to restructure your data to

```
>>> import collections
>>> c = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> c[1, 2] = 'foo'
>>> c[5, 6] = 'bar'
>>> c
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {(1, 2): 'foo', (5, 6): 'bar'})
```

depending on what you actually need.

Comment: This is a quality observation.