# Multi-level defaultdict with variable depth?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large list like:

```
[A][B1][C1]=1
[A][B1][C2]=2
[A][B2]=3
[D][E][F][G]=4
```

I want to build a multi-level dict like:

```
A
--B1
-----C1=1
-----C2=1
--B2=3
D
--E
----F
------G=4
```

I know that if I use recursive defaultdict I can write `table[A][B1][C1]=1`, `table[A][B2]=2`, but this works only if I hardcode those insert statement.

While parsing the list, I don't how many []'s I need beforehand to call `table[key1][key2][...]`.

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547643/convert-a-list-of-delimited-strings-to-a-tree-nested-dict-using-python

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can do it without even defining a class:

```
from collections import defaultdict

nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
nest = nested_dict()

nest[0][1][2][3][4][5] = 6
```

Comment: this is sweet!  but how about if i want leaves to  initialize via a standard (int, list, etc) factory?  eg, i want to be able to say:  `table[0][1][2][3][4][5] += 1`

Comment: is there a way to do the same with a built-in dict and .get() ?

Comment: @rikb: i don't see how without setting a fixed depth (to differentiate the leave-nodes)

Comment: class l(dict): __missing__=lambda a,b:a.setdefault(b,l()) and then continue from table=l()

Comment: PyCharm says it violates PEP 8: "do not assign a lambda expression use a def". Any ways to do this with a function to get rid of the warning?

Comment: def nested_dict(): return defaultdict(nested_dict) but i like the lambda version better. it looks a bit more cryptic ;-)

Comment: @MonsieurBeilto this gives an intro: https://howchoo.com/g/yjjknjdinmq/nested-defaultdict-python
Summary: defaultdict takes an argument: a function that is called if a key doesn't exist when the dict is indexed. The last examples in the link are of providing a function which itself returns a defaultdict which as its argument takes the function dict, returning a normal dict. Repeating this gets some fixed level of nesting. OP's answer is just making this process recursive, so the provided function to the inner default dict is itself our original function, giving arbitrary level of nesting.

Comment: What would be "the stopping condition" in this case for the nested_dict? What goes on behind the curtains when working with a lambda? Also, is there an equivalent of this without using lambdas?

Answer (score 20):

Your example says that at any level there can be a value, and also a dictionary of sub-elements. That is called a **tree**, and there are many implementations available for them. This is one:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Tree(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        super(Tree, self).__init__(Tree)
        self.value = value

root = Tree()
root.value = 1
root['a']['b'].value = 3
print root.value
print root['a']['b'].value
print root['c']['d']['f'].value
```

Outputs:

```
1
3
None
```

You could do something similar by writing the input in JSON and using `json.load` to read it as a structure of nested dictionaries.

Comment: I think the `value` construct is unnecessary, at least with respect to the proposed problem. Just remove references to `value` and assign values directly to dictionary keys.

Comment: +1: Although the `value` arg/attribute isn't really necessary.

Comment: @Martineau @Jason. The `value` instance variable is necessary because otherwise you'd loose the children when you assign directly to a node (see my comment to Jason's elegant solution). Intervening `__setitem__` would provide for a much more robust solution, but it would be a too complicated solution to the simple requirements.

Comment: I was unclear how to modify the other answers to that the collection property was a `list` instead of a `int/float`. This answer makes it clear, where  `self.value = []` was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 11):

I'd do it with a subclass of `dict` that defines `__missing__`:

```
>>> class NestedDict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...             self[key] = NestedDict()
...             return self[key]
...
>>> table = NestedDict()
>>> table['A']['B1']['C1'] = 1
>>> table
{'A': {'B1': {'C1': 1}}}
```

You can't do it directly with defaultdict because [defaultdict expects the factory function](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) at initialization time, but at initialization time, there's no way to describe the same defaultdict. The above construct does the same thing that default dict does, but since it's a named class (NestedDict), it can reference itself as missing keys are encountered. It is also possible to subclass defaultdict and override `__init__`.

Comment: That's not enough. You'll get an error if you try `table['A']['B1']['C1']['D2'] = 2`. The nodes must be able to hold a value **and** the children.

Comment: @Apalala: Actually, from the OP's example input, it appears that nodes only need to be able to hold a value **or** children, never both -- which is why @Jason and I claimed your answer's `value` attribute was unnecessary.

Comment: @martinau MHO is that it all becomes unstable (bug-prone) unless it is solved as a tree. Syntax and implementation are irrelevant. Is it, or is it not a problem that requires a tree structure? My point is that one should not force a design towards a _pretty_ syntax unless there are compelling reasons to do it. KISS.

Comment: @Apalala I know this is old. but how do we implement a `defaultdict` that holds both values and children?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez Look at Apalala's answer in this same question.

Answer (score 6):

This is equivalent to the above, but avoiding lambda notation. Perhaps easier to read ?

```
def dict_factory():
   return defaultdict(dict_factory)

your_dict = dict_factory()
```

Also -- from the comments -- if you'd like to update from an existing dict, you can simply call

```
your_dict[0][1][2].update({"some_key":"some_value"})
```

In order to add values to the dict.

Comment: This solution does not offer the ability to pass an initial value.  I think Dan O'Huiginn's solution (via Dvd Avins post) is slightly better for this reason.

Answer (score 4):

Dan O'Huiginn posted a very nice solution on his journal in 2010:

http://ohuiginn.net/mt/2010/07/nested_dictionaries_in_python.html

```
>>> class NestedDict(dict):
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         if key in self: return self.get(key)
...         return self.setdefault(key, NestedDict())


>>> eggs = NestedDict()
>>> eggs[1][2][3][4][5]
{}
>>> eggs
{1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {}}}}}}
```

Comment: I find this approach nice when I want to create a nested dictionary quickly.  If I want to "re-enable" `KeyError`, it's easy to convert back to a standard dictionary using `dict()`.

Comment: `return self.setdefault(key, NestedDict())` is sufficient.  No need for the if.

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve this with a recursive [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def tree():
    def the_tree():
        return defaultdict(the_tree)
    return the_tree()
```

It is important to protect the default factory name, `the_tree` here, in a closure ("private" local function scope).  Avoid using a one-liner `lambda` version, which is bugged due to Python's [late binding closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures), and implement this with a `def` instead.

The accepted answer, using a lambda, has a flaw where instances must rely on the `nested_dict` name existing in an outer scope. If for whatever reason the factory name can not be resolved (e.g. it was rebound or deleted) then pre-existing instances will also become subtly broken:

```
>>> nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
>>> nest = nested_dict()
>>> nest[0][1][2][3][4][6] = 7
>>> del nested_dict
>>> nest[8][9] = 10
# NameError: name 'nested_dict' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different possibility that allows regular dictionary initialization:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def superdict(arg=()):
    update = lambda obj, arg: obj.update(arg) or obj
    return update(defaultdict(superdict), arg)
```

Example:

```
>>> d = {"a":1}
>>> sd = superdict(d)
>>> sd["b"]["c"] = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Hugo 
To have a max depth:

```
l=lambda x:defaultdict(lambda:l(x-1)) if x>0 else defaultdict(dict)
arr = l(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `NestedDict`.

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

nd = NestedDict()
nd[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = 6
```

The result as a dictionary:

```
>>> nd.to_dict()
{0: {1: {2: {3: {4: {5: 6}}}}}}
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts)

```
pip install ndicts
```