# How do nested dicts perform vs. non nested dicts? (Python)

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, nested, text-files

I'm having trouble finding information about how nesting dicts affects performance. My assumption is nesting makes searches faster, but I just want to confirm that I'm understanding this correctly.

note: let's assume these dicts are much bigger (if the specific size is important, let me know)

Here are two examples:

```
people = 
{
    'person1':
        {
            'name':
                {
                    'first': 'John',
                    'middle': 'Charles',
                    'last': 'Doe'
                },
            'age': '27',
            'sex': 'Male',
        },
}
```

compared to:

```
people = 
{
    'person1':
        {
            'name': 'John Charles Doe',
            'firstname': 'John',
            'middlename': 'Charles',
            'lastname': 'Doe',
            'age': '27',
            'sex': 'Male',
        },
}
```

Comment: I imagine that there are different answers for different programming languages and their various implementations. Please [edit] the question to explain further.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I added the python tag. Sorry about that.

Comment: The answer here might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147785/nested-dictionaries-or-tuples-for-key

Comment: @YilunZhang Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nested dictionaries or tuples for key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147785/nested-dictionaries-or-tuples-for-key)

Comment: @perennial_noob Yes, possibly. I'm struggling to understand what that thread op is asking and whether it is the same as my question. My dict only goes 3 keys deep so maybe it's a non-issue.