# Python - Dynamic PHP-like arrays

Tags: python, django, arrays, multidimensional-array

I' trying to create a PHP like array in python. In Perl it would be a hash...

I want to organize content from the database in an array for easier access.

Something like:

```
myarray[db_numeric_value1][db_numeric_value2] = db_str_value
```

But no luck so far...

I tried to initialize myarray as an object list (myarray = {}) or as an array (myarray = [])... Also tried to initialize the "subarrays" but did not work either...

Thanks for your help!

Ron

Comment: see [this amazing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8702435/989121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use python's defaultdict with proper "default_factory":

```
from collections import defaultdict
myarray = defaultdict(dict)
myarray[4][5] = 34
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python it would be a `dictionary` ([see python data structures](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html))

```
In [4]: myarray = {3: {4: 'Hello World'}}

In [5]: myarray[3][4]
Out[5]: 'Hello World'
```

EDIT: the same thing but without initializing first

```
In [6]: myarray = {}
In [7]: myarray[3] = {}
In [9]: myarray[3][4] = 'Hello World'

In [10]: myarray[3][4]
Out[10]: 'Hello World'
```

Dictionary indexes can be also variables:

```
myarray[myindex] = myvalue
```

Comment: AFAIK I tried to use a list when I initialized myarray with these brackets: []... When do this, Python tells me that my list index is out of range... The thing is that its a dynamical list so there should be no boundry, right?

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet...but how do I do this dynamically. The thing is that I dont know my values because I get them from my database...

Comment: Ok... I really think I'm missing something... When I try your static code it works just fine. As soon as I put a variable between the brackets he complains... the error is just the key. for example: myarray[val] = "foo" then the error is just val, ie. 3

Comment: Show the **exact** code that fails, including all setup steps and the traceback.

Comment: `myarray` always has to be a dictionary first: `myarray = {}`

Comment: i did this... but the other solution works just fine. nevertheless: thanks :)