# How can I construct a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of strings, from which I have to construct a dict. So, for example, I have:

```
foo.bar:10
foo.hello.world:30
xyz.abc:40
pqr:100
```

This is represented as a dict:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": 10,
    "hello": {
      "world": 30
    }
  },
  "xyz": {
    "abc": 40
  },
  "pqr": 100
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369723/multi-level-defaultdict-with-variable-depth/8702435) is based on the same premise, but   the answers discuss hardcoded depths such as:

```
mydict = ...
mydict['foo']['bar'] = 30
```

Since the dot seperated strings on the left may be of any depth, I can't figure out a way to build the dict. How should I parse the dot separated string and build the dict?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547643/convert-a-list-of-delimited-strings-to-a-tree-nested-dict-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building upon the solution in the links, you could

1. iterate over each line
2. for each line, extract a list of keys, and its value
3. recurse into a dictionary with each key using `setdefault`
4. assign the value at the bottom

---

```
lines = \
'''
foo.bar:10
foo.hello.world:30
xyz.abc:40
pqr:100
'''.splitlines()

d = {}

for l in lines:
    k, v = l.split(':')
    *f, l = k.split('.')

    t = d
    for k in f:
        t = t.setdefault(k, {})
    t[l] = int(v)   # don't perform a conversion if your values aren't numeric
```

```
print(d)
{
    "pqr": 100,
    "foo": {
        "bar": 10,
        "hello": {
            "world": 30
        }
    },
    "xyz": {
        "abc": 40
    }
}
```

Recursive `setdefault` traversal learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547643/convert-a-list-of-delimited-strings-to-a-tree-nested-dict-using-python).

---

Breaking down each step -

1. Split on `:`, extract the key-list string and the value

   ```
   k, v = l.split(':')
   ```
2. Split the key-string on `.` to get a list of keys. I take the opportunity to partition the keys as well, so I have a separate reference to the last key that will be the key to `v`.

   ```
   *f, l = k.split('.')
   ```

   `*f` is the catch-all assignment, and `f` is a list of any number of values (possibly 0 values, if there's only one key in the key-string!)
3. For each key `k` in the key list `f`, recurse down into the "tree" using `setdefault`. This is similar to recursively traversing a linked list.

   ```
   for k in f:
       t = t.setdefault(k, {})
   ```
4. At the end, the last key value pair comes from `l` and `v`.

   ```
   t[l] = v
   ```

Comment: Like your solution, but don't like your naming :D

Comment: @user1767754 Haha, sorry about that. It's a community wiki, so feel free to modify. I didn't want to earn any rep from this answer because most of it was a derivative of the link, but not enough to answer the question.

Comment: Oh no...i'm not worried, it's just me being overly expressive with my naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with incrementally building it?

```
mydict = {}
mydict["foo"] = {}
mydict["foo"]["bar"] = 30
mydict["foo"]["hello"] = {}
mydict["foo"]["hello"]["world"] = 30
mydict["foo"]["xyz"] = {}
mydict["foo"]["xyz"]["abc"] = 40
mydict["foo"]["pqr"] = 100
# ...
pprint.pprint(mydict) # {'foo': {'bar': 30, 'hello': {'world': 30}, 'pqr': 100, 'xyz': {'abc': 40}}}
```

Including the parsing, you could use something like this:

```
import pprint

inp = """foo.bar:10
foo.hello.world:30
xyz.abc:40
pqr:100
"""

mydict = {}

for line in inp.splitlines():
    s, v = line.split(':')
    parts = s.split(".")
    d = mydict
    for i in parts[:-1]:
        if i not in d:
            d[i] = {}
        d = d[i]
    d[parts[-1]] = v

pprint.pprint(mydict) # {'foo': {'bar': '10', 'hello': {'world': 30'}}, 'pqr': '100', 'xyz': {'abc': '40'}}
```

Comment: I have to parse the dot-separated part of the string and construct the dict. Building it manually requires hardcoding, which isn't an option.

Comment: @user2064000: See my update. Building the dict incrementally works exactly the same when parsing.

Answer (score 0):

One key point to consider in your case is that you either want to create a dictionary in a parent's dictionarys value part `or` an integer

```
x = """
foo.bar:10
foo.hello.world:30
xyz.abc:40
pqr.a:100
"""

tree = {}

for item in x.split():
    level, value = item.split(":")[0], item.split(":")[1]

    t = tree
    for part in item.split('.'):
        keyval = part.split(":")
        if len(keyval) > 1:
            #integer
            t = t.setdefault(keyval[0], keyval[1])
        else:
            t = t.setdefault(part, {})


import pprint
pprint.pprint(tree)
```

**Result:**

```
{'foo': {'bar': '10', 'hello': {'world': '30'}},
 'pqr': {'a': '100'},
 'xyz': {'abc': '40'}}
```