# turn multi-level nested json or dictionary into readable excel report

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

Let's say I have a JSON or a dictionary.  I would like to generate an easy, human-readable Excel report out of it.

```
{'A1': 
    {'B1': 'XX1',
     'B2': 'XX2',
     'B3': 'XX4',
     'B4': {'C1': 'XX000'},
     'B8': 'XX5'
     }
  ...
}
```

How do I create a dataframe (more specifically an Excel report) that looks like this:

```
A1
B1   XX1
B2   XX2
B3   XX4
B4   C1    XX000
B8   XX5
```

Excel final Output:

[image: Example XLSX Output]

Any ideas welcome!  Assume that this is a multi-index JSON/dictionary and needs to be dynamically developed.

I have some basic code that returns me metadata containing tree-path, sub-depth, etc. but this is not getting me too far. Any suggestions?

---

Essentially, I need to create the opposite of this: [How to generate n-level hierarchical JSON from pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205399/how-to-generate-n-level-hierarchical-json-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: So you want to end up with a .csv file?

Comment: Sure, a `.csv` will work... I will eventually add some custom formatting using `xlsxwriter`, but for now it will do.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I don't even have enough rep to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of options, using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) or python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) module, see example below, you should tweak it to get the formatting you want

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A1': 
        {'B1': 'XX1',
         'B2': 'XX2',
         'B3': 'XX4',
         'B4': {'C1': 'XX000'},
         'B8': 'XX5'
        }
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_csv('mydata.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I should have been more specific with my question verbiage.. I can turn a dict into a dataframe, this is not the issue.  The issue is when we have randomly nested dictionaries scattered throughtout. Your proposition results in column `A1` row `B4` to display a dictionary, whereas I would need that dictionary to be spread open as well.  I cant seem to figure out a way to do this with recursion.

Comment: A large part of your solution will be completely custom to your situation for how you want the data parsed into rows and columns. For example, it's not intuitively obvious (to us) that you want the `{'C1': 'XX000'}` data on the same row as `B4`. Unless you lay out the specific rules for all the different situations your logic may encounter (such as nested dictionaries 3, 4, 5 or more levels deep), you're not going to get a ready-made solution here. The way it usually works for me is that when I sit down to define what those rules are, the coding logic works itself out and I solve it myself.