# Building a nested dictionary from a jagged excel file

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

I'm trying build a nested dictionary from a jagged excel file (image here:

[image]

), which I'm trying to add more 'children' to:

```
dict = {'levelA': {'levelA1': 'levelA11', 'LevelA2': 'LevelA21'},
'levelB': {'levelB1': 'levelB11'}, 
'levelC': {'levelC1': 'levelC12'}}
```

I want to find the value of:

```
"levelA21"
```

and replace it with a dictionary of the form:

```
['levelA21']['levelA211'] = "value"
```

I tried:

```
dict = {'levelA1': ["value1",  "value"],
   "LevelB1": ["value77", "something"] }
```

(wrong), and

```
"value" in [x for v in dict.values() for x in v]
```

which is true.

My code deals with the merged xls cells and removed NoneType from empty cells.

So after finding the dict.value() instance of "levelA21", can I replace it with a another nested level with key = "level21", item = "levelA211", and value = "value"?

Also, I'm removing the used keys and items, (first two columns), iteratively.

I think I should be building this recursively from right to left from the deepest (right-most) level and merging as I go, but I cannot grasp it.

Happy to share code class in entirety; it's documented pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps i can earn back some points with this link on building nested dictionaries with json files...

http://ohuiginn.net/mt/2010/07/nested_dictionaries_in_python.html

[Multi-level defaultdict with variable depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369723/multi-level-defaultdict-with-variable-depth)