# Create a deeply nested dictionnary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to create a python dictionnary that is 4 levels deep, I did it with a couple of conditions but I wondered if anyone knew of a better looking solution (and more efficient also).

A simplified example is the following:

```
data = {'a': 5}
dict_to_fill = {}
for key_string in key_string_list:
   first_key = key_string[0]
   second_key = key_string[1]
   third_key = key_string[2]
   fourth_key = key_string[2]
   if not first_key in dict_to_fill:
       dict_to_fill[first_key] = {}
   if not second_key in dict_to_fill[first_key]:
      dict_to_fill[first_key][second_key] = {}
   if not third_key in dict_to_fill[first_key][second_key]:
      dict_to_fill[first_key][second_key][third_key] = {}
   dict_to_fill[first_key][second_key][third_key][fourth_key] = data
```

What I would ideally like is to simply do this

```
dict_to_fill[first_key][second_key][third_key][fourth_key] = data
```

Where all the index errors are replaced by the creation of a dict so that I don't have to through all those conditions.

Comment: I suggest using a [recursive defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369723/multi-level-defaultdict-with-variable-depth) instead.

Comment: @timgeb, I was thinking how to do that exactly. Awesome!

Comment: Perfect, I hadn't seen this question while looking for the answer. This works very well.

Comment: Please define `key_string_list`