# How to loop a yaml to make another yaml with variables

Tags: python, loops, ansible, yaml

Dictionary of new variable is:

```
yaml_cluster = defaultdict(dict)
```

I have this yaml_file in a variable in python using safe_load from yaml library:

```
domainInfo:
    AdminUserName: '--FIX ME--'
    AdminPassword: '--FIX ME--'
topology:
    Name: 'wld-pil-10'
    ConfigBackupEnabled: true
    AdminServerName: 'wls-pil-10-sa-adm-n0'
    DomainVersion: 12.2.1.4.0
    ProductionModeEnabled: true
    ArchiveConfigurationCount: 20
    Cluster:
        'test-bruno-jee-r01a-c01':
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
    Server:
        'test-bruno-jee-r01a-it-c01-m1-n1':
            ListenPort: 10022
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            NMSocketCreateTimeoutInMillis: 30000
            Machine: 'wlm-pil-10-n1'
        'test-bruno-jee-r02a-it-c01-m1-n1':
            ListenPort: 10025
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            NMSocketCreateTimeoutInMillis: 30000
            Machine: 'wlm-pil-10-n2'
        'wls-pil-10-sa-adm-n0':
            ListenPort: 11030
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            Machine: 'wlm-pil-10-n0'
```

How to select just the first two of them? I tried this but without success:

```
servers = sorted(yaml_file["topology"]["Server"])[:-1]

for server in yaml_file["topology"]["Server"]:
    if server in servers:
        yaml_cluster["topology"]["Server"][server] = yaml_file["topology"]["Server"][server]
```

ERROR:

> fatal: [wls-pil-103-sa-adm-n0]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg":
> "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Traceback (most recent
> call last):\n  File
> "/home/split_yaml.py",
> line 40, in \n
> yaml_cluster["topology"]["Server"][server] =
> yaml_file["topology"]["Server"][server] #TypeError: string indices
> must be integers\nKeyError: 'Server'\n", "stderr_lines": ["Traceback
> (most recent call last):", "  File
> "/home/split_yaml.py",
> line 40, in ", "
> yaml_cluster["topology"]["Server"][server] =
> yaml_file["topology"]["Server"][server] **#TypeError: string indices
> must be integers", "KeyError: 'Server'"**], "stdout": "",
> "stdout_lines": []}

I think that there are two problems here

yaml_cluster["topology"]**["Server"][server]** = yaml_file["topology"]["Server"][server]
The "Server" and the variable server in the side of the yaml_cluster.
I think the dictionary does not let me assign those values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
yaml_cluster = defaultdict(dict)
```

If you do `yaml_cluster["topology"]` and that key doesn't exist, the defaultdict will use the given factory to construct it. Thus, it will return an empty `dict`. You then do `["Server"]` on that dict, and it doesn't exist. Since you now have a simple dict, not a defaultdict, this will result in a `KeyError`.

Do this instead ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702435/347964)):

```
nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
yaml_cluster = nested_dict()
```

Also, you can simplify the loop to

```
for server in servers:
  yaml_cluster["topology"]["Server"][server] = yaml_file["topology"]["Server"][server]
```

Comment: thanks ! my output file is full of this `topology: !!python/object/apply:collections.defaultdict
    args:
    - *id001
    dictitems:
      Server: !!python/object/apply:collections.defaultdict
        args:
        - *id001
        dictitems:
          test-bruno-jee-r01a-it-c01-m1-n1:`

Comment: @shamaN I assume you don't it to look like that. I suggest using normal dicts and implementing a function that handles the auto-creation then, like `set_path(yaml_cluster, ["topology", "Server", server], yaml_file["topology"]["Server"][server])` but if you need further assistance, please ask another question since that is not the focus of this one.