# Defining a dictionary of dictionaries with vectors as inner and outer keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to define a huge sparse matrix, which row index of the matrix is a 5 vector of size 5 and column index of of the matrix is also a vector of size 5. To be more specific, To retrieve an element in this matrix I need to know two vectors:

1. One is a vector for row, let's call it `(i,j,k,l,m)`. Where `i=1,...,20,j=1,...,10, k=1,...,10, l=1,...,10, m=1,...,10.`
2. One for column, let's call it `(n,o,p,q,r)`. Where Similarly,
   `n=1,...,20, o=1,...,10, p=1,...,10, q=1,...,10, r=1,...,10`.

   I am
   trying to implement the idea of dictionary of dictionaries where
   each key of the `Dict_1` dictionary refers to another dictionary,
   let's call it `Dict_2`. Where keys of `Dict_1` are vectors for *row* and
   *keys* of `Dict_2` are vectors for column.

I really appreciate any hint or help in defining this dictionary. I look into [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python) but couldn't
figure out how to extend that idea to the case where my row and
column keys are vectors. I really appreciate any help, comment.

Comment: What is a vector? Do you mean a tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have your dictionary like so:

`matrix = { (v1,v2):val}`

So for example:

```
>>> m = {((1,2,3,4),(9,8,8,2)):"info"}
>>> m[((1,2,3,4),(9,8,8,2))]
'info'
```

If you required a setup like:
`matrix = { v1: { v2:val }}`, you might use a `deafultdict` like so:

```
>>> matrix = defaultdict(dict)
>>> matrix[(1,2,3,4)][(9,8,8,2)] = "info"
>>> matrix
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {(1, 2, 3, 4): {(9, 8, 8, 2): 'info'}})
>>> matrix[(1,2,3,4)][(9,8,8,2)]
'info'
```

Comment: Thank you; this helps a lot. Just another quick question. Is it possible to do similar thing with dok_matrix from scipy? I am dealing with sparse matrices and it would help if I can use scipy's tools. I tried the following, but got errors:    from collections import defaultdict
    from scipy.sparse import *    
    from scipy import *    
    S = dok_matrix((9,9))    
        
    for i in range(3):    
        for j in range(3):    
            for k in range(3):    
                for l in range(3):    
                    S[(i,j)][(k,l)]=i+j+k+l