# Accessing nested values in nested dictionaries in Python 3.3

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I'm writing in Python 3.3.

I have a set of nested dictionaries (shown below) and am trying to search using a key at the lowest level and return each of the values that correspond to the second level.

```
Patients = {}
Patients['PatA'] = {'c101':'AT', 'c367':'CA', 'c542':'GA'}
Patients['PatB'] = {'c101':'AC', 'c367':'CA', 'c573':'GA'}
Patients['PatC'] = {'c101':'AT', 'c367':'CA', 'c581':'GA'}
```

I'm trying to use a set of 'for loops' to search pull out the value attached to the c101 key in each Pat* dictionary nested under the main Patients dictionary.

This is what I have so far:

```
pat = 'PatA'
mutations = Patients[pat]

for Pat in Patients.values(): #iterate over the Pat* dictionaries
    for mut in Pat.keys(): #iterate over the keys in the Pat* dictionaries
        if mut == 'c101': #when the key in a Pat* dictionary matches 'c101'
            print(Pat[mut].values()) #print the value attached to the 'c101' key
```

I get the following error, suggesting that my for loop returns each value as a string and that this can't then be used as a dictionary key to pull out the value.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "filename", line 13, in
>
> for mut in Pat.keys():
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

I think I'm missing something obvious to do with the dictionaries class, but I can't quite tell what it is. I've had a look through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python/636138#636138), but I don't think its quite what I'm asking.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. `for Pat in Patients.keys()` makes `Pat` one of the keys, which are strings; so of course it won't have a `.keys()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Patients.keys()` gives you the list of keys in Patients dictionary (`['PatA', 'PatC', 'PatB']`) not the list of values hence the error. You can use `dict.items` to iterate over key: value pairs like this:

```
for patient, mutations in Patients.items():
    if 'c101' in mutations.keys():
         print(mutations['c101'])
```

To make your code working:

```
# Replace keys by value
for Pat in Patients.values():
    # Iterate over keys from Pat dictionary
    for mut in Pat.keys():
        if mut == 'c101':
            # Take value of Pat dictionary using
            # 'c101' as a key
            print(Pat['c101'])
```

If you want you can create list of mutations in simple one-liner:

```
[mutations['c101'] for p, mutations in Patients.items() if mutations.get('c101')]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, works exactly as I wanted. Just to clarify, the 'for' statement takes the patient (keys) and mutations (values of patient keys). Then the 'if' searches the mutations as keys to pull out the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Patients = {}
Patients['PatA'] = {'c101':'AT', 'c367':'CA', 'c542':'GA'}
Patients['PatB'] = {'c101':'AC', 'c367':'CA', 'c573':'GA'}
Patients['PatC'] = {'c101':'AT', 'c367':'CA', 'c581':'GA'}

for keys,values in Patients.iteritems():
   # print keys,values
    for keys1,values1 in values.iteritems():
            if keys1 is 'c101':
                print keys1,values1
                #print values1
```