# properly getting data from nested dictionaries, there must be a better way

Tags: python, dictionary

I come across this issue on a regular basis, hopefully someone has an elegant solution...

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':{'c':2}}
```

now:

```
x.get('a', None) = 1

x.get('b', None).get('c', None) = 2
```

what about:

```
x.get('a', None).get('c', None) = 


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-278862f593e8> in <module>()
----> 1 x.get('a', None).get('c')

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

## #

Is there a simple pythonic one-liner for handling cases like this? (without using a bunch of *if* statements)

Thanks!

### #

Thanks for all the comments/feedback. I'm looking for an elegant one-liner, as I come across this on a regular basis. Obviously this is a toy-example, which was constructed just to explain the problem. I would prefer not to use try/catch blocks or wrap the code in long *if* statements. Thanks!

Comment: You quite often try to assign to a key using `get` and default values of `None`? Really??? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Your request, `x.get('a', None).get('c', None)` is not going to work, because 'a' doesn't have 'c' nested underneath it.

Comment: ``.get``, as the name implies, can't be used to assign values to a dict key. ``d.get(1, None)`` is a syntax error. In addition, the ``None`` is redundant in the first place, because the ``get`` method already returns ``None`` if the requested key isn't in the dict (the second argument is optional, and is used to override that behavior).

Comment: I see you're trying to build a 'tree' of data, not simply nested dicts. Is it correct?

Comment: The data is inherently unstructured, which means that not each node has the same number of branches.

Answer (score 2):

The usual syntax to access nested dictionary keys is:

```
>>> x = {'a':1, 'b':{'c':2}}
>>> x['b']['c']
2
>>> x['b']['c'] = 100
>>> x['b']['c']
100
```

This will throw a key error on missing keys:

```
>>> x['b']['d']
...
KeyError: 'd'
```

Which you could wrap in a try-catch:

```
>>> try:
...     x['b']['d']
... except KeyError as err:
...     # do something when no key is present ...
...     pass
```

If you are looking for a "catch-all non-existing keys and always do the right thing" kind of solution, I guess you'll have to write some thin wrapper around your specific data structure.

Comment: And without try/except, it will cause an exception on x['a']['c']

Comment: The problem is that the nodes of the tree have an un-equal number of branches.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generator that will grab the nested value if it's nested, and just the value if it isn't nested:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':{'c':2}}
def get_value(x, nested_key='c'):
    for k, v in x.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield v[nested_key]
        else:
            yield v
```

Here's a demo:

```
>>> for value in get_value(x):
        print (value)


2
1
```

Comment: ok, so we can get endpoints like this. what about the nodes? might not be in scope for the answer, [but as you know I like creating these kinds of data structures...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python/19829714#19829714)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a Pythonic one liner. Arbitrary nesting requires some arbitrary code. The Pythonic way is to ask for forgiveness meaning a try-catch block.

Think this through and it makes sense. Imagine debugging your nested get call above if it worked. Which layer was missing the key?

Comment: I agree, but I wouldn't call it arbitrary nesting, as it entails having to work with highly unstructured data. The point of the post was to see if someone had a clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean such construction:

```
try:
    x['a']['b'] = 1  # getting or setting values for existing dicts/keys
except:
    pass  # or do something in case dict does not exists
```