# Python dictionary key error when assigning - how do I get around this?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I have a dictionary that I create like this:

```
myDict = {}
```

Then I like to add key in it that corresponds to another dictionary, in which I put another value:

```
myDict[2000]['hello'] = 50
```

So when I pass `myDict[2000]['hello']` somewhere, it would give `50`.

Why isn't Python just creating those entries right there? What's the issue? I thought KeyError only occurs when you try to read an entry that doesn't exist, but I'm creating it right here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`KeyError` occurs because you are trying to read a non-existant key when you try to access `myDict[2000]`.  As an alternative, you could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> myDict = defaultdict(dict)
>>> myDict[2000]['hello'] = 50
>>> myDict[2000]
{'hello': 50}
```

`defaultdict(dict)` means that if myDict encounters an unknown key, it will return a default value, in this case whatever is returned by dict() which is an empty dictionary.

Comment: Where did you define `dict`? or that a primitive?

Comment: Yes, dict is a built-in type.

Answer (score 16):

What you want is to [implement a nested dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python/19829714#19829714):

I recommend this approach:

```
class Vividict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value
```

From the docs, under `d[key]`

> [New in version 2.5: If a subclass of dict defines a method
>   `__missing__()`, if the key `key` is not present, the d[key]
>   operation calls that method with the key key as argument](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

To try it:

```
myDict = Vividict()

myDict[2000]['hello'] = 50
```

and myDict now returns:

```
{2000: {'hello': 50}}
```

And this will work for any arbitrary depth you want:

```
myDict['foo']['bar']['baz']['quux']
```

just works.

Comment: Such an underrated answer...

Answer (score 14):

But you *are* trying to read an entry that doesn't exist: `myDict[2000]`.

The exact translation of what you say in your code is "give me the entry in myDict with the key of 2000, and store 50 against the key 'hello' in that entry." But myDict doesn't have a key of 2000, hence the error.

What you actually need to do is to create that key. You can do that in one go:

```
myDict[2000] = {'hello': 50}
```

Comment: That'll discard any existing entries for other keys in `myDict[2000]`, though. A `defaultdict(dict)` is probably worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

According to the below scenario, when you append `type new_result` into `dict`, you will get `KeyError: 'result'`

```
    dict = {}
    new_result = {'key1':'new_value1','key2':'new_value'}
    dict['result'].append(new_result)
```

Because key doesn't exist in other words your `dict` doesn't have a result key. I fixed this problem with `defaultdict` and their `setdefault` method.

To try it;

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    dict = defaultdict(dict)
    new_result = {'key1':'new_value1','key2':'new_value2'}
    dict.setdefault('result', []).append(new_result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right, but in your code python has to first get myDict[2000] and then do the assignment. Since that entry doesn't exist it can't assign to its elements

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to initialize a dict item, and assign an empty dict item for the outer key value. For example you can assign values with nested loops once you initialize your assignment dictionary.

```
myDict={}
counter=0
for outerKey in ['a','b']:
    myDict[outerKey]={}  # initialize a dict whose elements are dictionary
    for innerKey in ['c','d']:
        counter+=1
        myDict[outerKey][innerKey]=counter # assign using key values
print(myDict)
```

Output yields:

{'a': {'c': 1, 'd': 2}, 'b': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}}