# Python - adding key value parts to empty dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I've created a dictionary instance without any key: value pairs, standard

```
dict = {}
```

I'm then returning back some information from an API to be added to this dictionary dependent on some variables **name**.

```
some_variables_name1 = str(some_variable1)

dict[some_variables_name1] += [{ 'key1': value1 }]

some_variables_name2 = str(some_variable2)

dict[some_variables_name2] += [{ 'key2': value2 }]
```

However, I seem to be getting an error similar to this *Assuming that str(some_variable1) is equal to `'foo'`:

```
KeyError: 'foo'
```

Any pro tips?

Comment: you can directly give like this : `dict[some_variables_name1] = value1` right ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar Yeh, and I want `value1` to be a further nesting of data...

Comment: So can you mention any sample o/p you are expecting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary key error when assigning - how do I get around this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089383/python-dictionary-key-error-when-assigning-how-do-i-get-around-this)

Comment: You can define your `dict = defaultdict(list)` instead of `dict = {}`

Comment: You may find useful [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method of `dict`.

Comment: @MichaelRobers, as per above comment I've included `defaultdict` method below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers already adressed why this fails, here is a convenient solution that sets a default for if the key is not already present, such that your appending does not fail. 
The way I read it, you want a dictionary with lists of other dictionaries as values. Imagining a situation such as

```
somedict = {}
somevar = 0
somevar_name = str(somevar)

key1 = "oh"
value1 = 1
```

You can do

```
somedict.setdefault(somevar_name,[]).append({key1,value1})
```

This will evaluate to

> {'0': [{'oh', 1}]}

In other words, change lines of this sort

```
somedict[some_variables_name] += [{ 'somekey': somevalue }]
```

Into:

```
somedict.setdefault(some_variables_name,[]).append({'somekey':somevalue})
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: more pythonic way... :)

Answer (score 4):

@Harsha is right.

This:

```
dict[some_variables_name1] += [{ 'key1': value1 }]
```

Will do:

```
dict[some_variables_name1] = dict[some_variables_name1] + [{ 'key1': value1 }]
```

Right-Hand-Side needs to be evaluated first so, it will try to lookup:

```
dict[some_variables_name1]
```

Which will fail.

Comment: more pythonic way... :)

Answer (score 4):

The pythonic solution is to set default values for your dictionary. In my opinion, [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is the best option for this.

Also, please do not use variables names which are also classes. I have called the dictionary `d` below.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

some_variables_name1 = str(some_variable1)
d[some_variables_name1].append({'key1': value1})

some_variables_name2 = str(some_variable2)
d[some_variables_name2].append({'key2': value2})
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to first check is "foo" present in `dictionary` as a key.

You can try:

```
if "foo" in dict_name:
    dict_name.append("new_append")
else:
    dict_name["foo"] = ["first entry"]
```

**Small suggestion:** do not use `dict` as dictionary variable as it is **keyword** in Python

Comment: Yeh I was just using that as an example placeholder for the purposes of the question.

Answer (score 1):

to create a new dictionary use:

```
dict = dict()
```

When you try to add something you use:

```
+=
```

There is nothing to add. you have to first create the value

```
dict[some_variables_name1] = [{ 'key1': value1 }]
```

As also suggested do not use `dict`.. a simple `d` that means dict is the way forward.

Comment: @johnashu Hi, yeh didn't quite work. Thank you tho (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @johnashu Your amending suggestion worked. Of course, it doesn't exist so can't `+=` to it just need to set it with `=`. Stupid! Will accept as correct answer when I can. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary is of only one pair of key and value, I found using dictionary zip can be handy (beforehand collected all keys  and values in separate lists and than zip them to construct a new dictionary which like adding those dictionaries).

Here my example

> " I want to make {c} = {{a}, {b}}"

```
c = { }
a = {"100": "1.1"}
b = {"200": "1.2"}

# d and e just dummies
d = [ ]
e = [ ]
for item in [a, b]:
    d += list(item)
    e += list(item.values())

c = dict(zip(d,e))
print(c)

"  c  = {'100': '1.1', '200': '1.2'} “
```

Comment: Sorry, I just found dictionary update even more handy
```
c = { }
a = {"100": "1.1"}
b = {"200": "1.2", "300":"1.3"}
c.update(a)
c.update(b)
c
"{'100': '1.1', '200': '1.2', '300': '1.3'}"
```