# Python, is there a easier way to add values to a default key?

Tags: python-2.7

The program I am working does the following:

- Grabs stdout from a .perl program
- Builds a nested dict from the output

I'm using the AutoVivification approach found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python) to build a default nested dictionary. I'm using this method of defaultdict because it's easier for me to follow as a new programmer.

I'd like to add one key value to a declared key per pass of the `for line` in the below code. Is there a easier way to add values to a key beyond making a `[list]`  of values then adding said values as a group?

```
import pprint

class Vividict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

reg = 'NtUser'
od = Vividict()
od[reg]

def run_rip():
    os.chdir('/Users/ME/PycharmProjects/RegRipper2.8')  # Path to regripper dir
    for k in ntDict:
        run_command = "".join(["./rip.pl", " -r 
                              /Users/ME/Desktop/Reg/NTUSER.DAT -p ", str(k)])  
        process = subprocess.Popen(run_command,
                               shell=True,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = process.communicate()  # wait for the process to terminate
        parse(out)
        # errcode = process.returncode // used in future for errorcode checking
        ntDict.popitem(last=False)

def parse(data):
    pattern = re.compile('lastwrite|(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})|alert|trust|Value')
    grouping = re.compile('(?P<first>.+?)(\n)(?P<second>.+?)
                         ([\n]{2})(?P<rest>.+[\n])', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    if pattern.findall(data):
        match = re.search(grouping, data)
        global first
        first = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", match.group('first'))
        od[reg][first]
        second = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", match.group('second'))
        parse_sec(second)

def parse_sec(data):
    pattern = re.compile(r'^(\(.*?\)) (.*)$')
    date = re.compile(r'(.*?\s)(.*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*)$')
    try:
        if pattern.match(data):
            result = pattern.match(data)
            hive = result.group(1)
            od[reg][first]['Hive'] = hive
            desc = result.group(2)
            od[reg][first]['Description'] = desc

        elif date.match(data):
            result = date.match(data)
            hive = result.group(1)
            od[reg][first]['Hive'] = hive
            time = result.group(2)
            od[reg][first]['Timestamp'] = time

        else:
            od[reg][first]['Finding'] = data

    except IndexError:
         print('error w/pattern match')

run_rip()
pprint.pprint(od)
```

Sample Input:

```
bitbucket_user v.20091020
(NTUSER.DAT) TEST - Get user BitBucket values

Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\BitBucket
LastWrite Time Sat Nov 28 03:06:35 2015 (UTC)

Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\BitBucket\Volume
LastWrite Time = Sat Nov 28 16:00:16 2015 (UTC)
```

Comment: @Jonrsharpe I noticed you edited/removed my add-on question, since there is no way to message directly can you elaborate on why you thought it was not relevant?

Comment: ...because your add-on question *was irrelevant*, it's simply not on-topic. That kind of meta-content is not appropriate for questions on SO - if you want to discuss things like that, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know if your a mod, or someone with just a high score count. But as you can tell by my flair I'm new. Since I'm engaging you I would hope it's obvious I want to improve my ability to accurately depict a SO problem and it is frustrating as a user to be immediately down-voted on topics that are considered remedial to the more experienced user-base. Is there a better meta to ask these kind of "beginner" questions?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're asking in this question. It seems like you're asking about something in loop, but it's all abstracted away by your `#do stuff` comment. Can you more clearly explain what you're doing and what you want to do differently?

Comment: @Blckknght formatted for readability, please let me know if it helps? I'm trying to learn how SE works and contribute questions that make sense.

Comment: It's still not actually valid syntactically, please give a [mcve].

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking for. What `[list]` are you talking about? That's not anywhere in your code. What do you mean by "build dict per pass"? How does that differ from what you're doing now?

Comment: @Blckknght the current interaction is a tuple and I'm unsure how to interact with the dict in a way that will allow me to add additional values beyond the most recent. Since the dict is being declared on the fly is there a temp variable I should call to do a append?

Comment: @jonrsharpe read your link, I hope the above is more in-line with the expectations set forth in that guide.

Comment: Not really, it doesn't say what output you expected and what you got instead and isn't exactly minimal

Comment: @jonrsharpe so how would I present the dependancies in the script in a minimalist way? Is there another way to ask how to add more than one value to a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to change the lines where you're actually adding values to your dictionary (e.g. the `od[reg][first]['Hive'] = hive` line and the similar one for `desc` and `time`) to create a list for each `reg` and `first` value and then extend that list with each item being added. Your dictionary subclass takes care of creating the nested dictionaries for you, but it won't build a list at the end.

I think the best way to do this is to use the `setdefault` method on the inner dictionary:

```
od[reg][first].setdefault("Hive", []).append(hive)
```

The `setdefault` will add the second value (the "default", here an empty list) to the dictionary if the first argument doesn't exist as a key. It preempts the dictionary's `__missing__` method creating the item, which is good, since we want a the value to be list rather than another layer of dictionary. The method returns the value for the key in all cases (whether it added a new value or if there was one already), so we can chain it with `append` to add our new `hive` value to the list.