# One line tree implementation

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, autovivification

[Based of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19829714/232794), I want to create a [one line tree](https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250) as part of another class like thus:

```
self._tree = collections.defaultdict(lambda: self._tree)
```

I will need to allow the users of said class to add path elements to the tree and run some callback starting at the lowest tree level.  My naive implementation raises a error when I run `pytest`:

```
def _add(self, tree, path):
    for node in path:
        tree = tree[node]

def _run(self, tree, callback):
    for key in tree.keys():
        callback(tree[key]) # !!! Recursion detected (same locals & position)
        self._run(key)
```

This code works iff the tree is defined as

```
    def tree():
        return collections.defaultdict(tree)

    self._tree = tree()
```

**Why is my naive approach not working with the lambda expression?**

---

⚠ The [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states that

> Simple is better than complex.

The one-line lambda makes the code complex where there is a [simpler implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19829714/232794). Therefore the one-line lambda **should not be used in production code**. However, I shall leave this question here for academic interest.

Comment: The method passed to `defaultdict` must create a new instance, not reference back to an existing object.  In your case `tree` is a method that returns a new `defaultdict(tree)`, but your one-liner is a lambda that returns the original `self._tree` instance of `defaultdict(lambda: etc.)`

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Then why does `d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: d); d['foo']['bar']` seems to work fine despite being ugly when printed?

Comment: Kevin's answer and Tadhg McDonald-Jensen's comment illustrate the improper recursion in the one-line lambda approach.

Comment: looking back at the [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python/19829714#19829714) it was behaving the exact same way: instead of creating new sub dicts it only creates a reference to itself. (it shows {...} for dictionaries that are already displayed in recursive structure)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one-line defaultdict design in the first linked question doesn't look right to me. It produces unusual self-referential loops:

```
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: d)
>>> d["a"] = 23
>>> d["b"]["c"] = 42
>>> print d["b"]["a"] #we never created a value with these keys, so it should just return a defaultdict instance.
23
>>> #uh, that's not right...
```

A one-line lambda implementation of the function in your second link would look more like:

`tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree); self._tree = tree()`

---

Edit: looks like you can do it in a single statement with:

```
self._tree = (lambda f: f(f))(lambda t: defaultdict(lambda: t(t)))
```

... But requiring college-level lambda calculus skills just to shrink your script by one statement seems like an unwise bargain. Consider a more understandable approach.

Comment: this is easy to verify with `assert d is d['b']` before a value is set to the key 'b'.  it just refers back to itself.

Comment: To preempt any comments asking "ok but can you do it in one line with no semicolons?" I think it's theoretically possible but it requires some rather tricky uses of lambda. Fixed-point combinators may be required. I'm still playing around with it.

Comment: @Kevin: Thank you! Of course one should not be [assigning lambda in the first place](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: I got it with one line, I don't like it even a little bit but I got it.

Comment: 100% agree with your final statement, question edited to make that clear for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

even with the code from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python/19829714#19829714) it is having the exact same issue:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(lambda:d)
assert d is d[1] is d[2][4]
```

every sub dict is only creating a reference to itself instead of a new dictionary.

in order for this to work properly the lambda needs to create a new `defaultdict` object with itself (the lambda expression) as the first argument.  However the only reference to the lambda is kept as `self._tree.default_factory` so the one-liner would have to look like this:

```
self._tree = collections.defaultdict(lambda:collections.defaultdict(self._tree.default_factory))
```

This is so inherently confusing that I cannot stress enough how much *I recommend **against** doing it in one line.*

Comment: 100% agree with your final statement, question edited to make that clear for future readers.