# Appending list values to a dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a python script and I am stuck with the dictionaries. I have read through some of the other forums but can't seem to get anywhere.  I am a very new python programmer so please be gentle.

What I want to do:

1)  set up a dictionary like this:  `{'Name':'userid','jobid:jobid','walltime:walltime,'nodes:nds'}`

2)  iterate through a list of entries created from and external function call and extract information to populate the dictionary

3)  Problem:  I cannot figure out how to append entries to the appropriate keys

For example, I want this:

```
{‘Name’:’jose’,’jobid’:’001,002,003,005’,’walltime:32:00,240:00,04:00,07:00’,’nodes’:32,32,500’}
```

Notice for one userid, I have multiple jobids, walltimes and nodes.
`(len(jobids)==len(walltimes)==len(nodes)` for any one userid but can vary across userids)

I am able to get the script to find the first value for each username, but it never appends.  How can I get this to append?

Here is what I have tried

```
from collections import defaultdict
pdict = defaultdict(list)

start the loop:

 # get new values – add these to the dictionary keyed 
 # on username (create a new entry or append to existing entry)
    …
    (jobid,userid,jobname, sessid, nds, tsk, walltime,rest)= m.groups()  

    ...
    if userid in pdict:
       print "DEBUG: %s is currently in the dictionary -- appending entries" %(userid)
       pdict[userid][‘jobid’] = pdict[userid][jobid].append(jobid)    I 
     # repeat for nodes, walltime, etc 

    if not userid in pdict:
        print "DEBUG: %s is not in the dictionary creating entry" %(userid)
        pdict[userid] = {}  # define a dictionary within a dictionary with key off userid
        pdict[userid]['jobid'] = jobid
        pdict[userid]['jobname'] = jobname
        pdict[userid]['nodes'] = nds
        pdict[userid]['walltime'] = walltime
```

I know this is wrong but can’t figure out how to get the append to work.  I have tried many of the suggestions offered on this site. I need to append (to the dictionary) the most recent values from the loop keyed to userid

Here is an example of the ouput – it does not append multiple entries for each userid but rather takes only the first value for each userid

> userid jmreill contains data: {'nodes': '1', 'jobname':
>   'A10012a_ReMig_Q', 'walltime': '230:0', 'jobid': '1365582'}
>
> userid igorysh contains data: {'nodes': '20', 'jobname':
>   'emvii_Beam_fwi6', 'walltime': '06:50', 'jobid': '1398100'}

Any suggestions?  This should be easy but I can’t figure it out!

Comment: Do you get an error? Perhaps `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`? You have to create lists for the keys that will hold multiple values, then you'll be able to `append()`. So something like `pdict[userid]['jobid'] = [jobid]`

Comment: It is more pythonic to use `if userid not in pdict` instead of `if not userid in pdict`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

pdict = defaultdict(dict)

start the loop:

 # get new values – add these to the dictionary keyed 
 # on username (create a new entry or append to existing entry)
    …
    (jobid,userid,jobname, sessid, nds, tsk, walltime,rest)= m.groups()  

    ...
    if userid in pdict:
       print "DEBUG: %s is currently in the dictionary -- appending entries" %(userid)
       pdict[userid][jobid].append(jobid)
     # repeat for nodes, walltime, etc 

    if userid not in pdict:
        print "DEBUG: %s is not in the dictionary creating entry" %(userid)
        pdict[userid]['jobid'] = [jobid]
        pdict[userid]['jobname'] = jobname
        pdict[userid]['nodes'] = nds
        pdict[userid]['walltime'] = walltime
```

Comment: And replace the line `pdict[userid]['jobid'] = jobid` with `pdict[userid]['jobid'] = [jobid]`

Comment: @sparkandshine Yes! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The value corresponding to key `'jobid'` should be a list of strings rather than a string. If you create your dictionary this way, you can append new jobid's to the list simply by:

```
pdict[userid]['jobid'].append(jobid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant remember the explanation why to use the lambda expression in the following code, but you have to define a `defaultdict` of a `defaultdict`:

```
pdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

pdict[userid][‘jobid’].append('1234')
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

The `append()` method does not return the list...it is modified in place.  Also, you need to initialize your elements as lists (using square brackets):

```
if userid in pdict:
   print "DEBUG: %s is currently in the dictionary -- appending entries" %(userid)
   pdict[userid][jobid].append(jobid)  ## just call append here
 # repeat for nodes, walltime, etc 

if not userid in pdict:
    print "DEBUG: %s is not in the dictionary creating entry" %(userid)
    pdict[userid] = {}  # define a dictionary within a dictionary with key off userid
    pdict[userid]['jobid'] = [jobid,]  ## initialize with lists
    pdict[userid]['jobname'] = [jobname,]
    pdict[userid]['nodes'] = [nds,]
    pdict[userid]['walltime'] = [walltime,]
```

Answer (score 0):

append doesn't return a value, it modifies the list in place, and you forgot to quote 'jobid' on the right of equals. So you should replace `pdict[userid][‘jobid’] = pdict[userid][jobid].append(jobid)` with `pdict[userid]['jobid'].append(jobid)`. Also take into account comment from @Jasper.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a dict of dicts? `AutoVivification` is the perfect solution. Implement the perl’s autovivification feature in Python.

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value​
```

This makes everything easier. Note that the value of `pdict[userid]['jobid']` should be a list `[jobid]` instead of a variable `jobid` as you have multiple `jobid`.

```
pdict = AutoVivification()

if userid in pdict:
    pdict[userid]['jobid'].append(jobid) 
else:
    pdict[userid]['jobid'] = [jobid] # a list
```

Refer to [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python).