# Autovivification of nested dictionary with lists to append in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been trying to implement autovivification for python dictionary. I have referred the following links as well which has helped me to achieve what I wanted, but partially.

[What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries/19829714#19829714)

[How to implement autovivification for nested dictionary ONLY when assigning values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122577/how-to-implement-autovivification-for-nested-dictionary-only-when-assigning-valu)

This is the example I have been trying for my purpose

```
class MyDict(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, keys, value):
       if not isinstance(keys, tuple):
           return dict.__setitem__(self, keys, value)

       for key in keys[:-1]:
           self = self.setdefault(key, {})
       dict.__setitem__(self, keys[-1], value)
```

This is working for normal cases such as

```
my_dict = MyDict()
my_dict['a','b','c']=10
```

which results in :  `{'a': {'b': {'c': 10}}}`

But how do i implement this which is very much possible with *collections.defaultdict*

`my_dict['a']['b']['c'].append(10)`

I don't want to implement *defaultdict* because of it's non-human-readable output and moreover it is not working with pickle.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Subclass `defaultdict` to customize its `__repr__` and allow it to be pickled? (Seems to work fine with pickle to me, though.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. One more reason I want to avoid defaultdict is , initialization gets uglier when the dictionary is deeply nested.

Comment: Although I tried this way as well `tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)`, but I failed to handle this case in a recursive way - `defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list)))`

Comment: `tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)` didn’t work?

Comment: Hi, Actually it is working for dictionary of dictionaries but I am not able to come up with a code for *dict-of-dict-of-list* as i mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: If the structure is fixed, you can come up with a function that creates `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)))` from `(3, list)`. If it isn’t, you can subclass `defaultdict` to add `append` and whatever else is necessary to act like a list, but that’s kind of messy and I’d make a function that initializes `my_dict['a']['b']['c'] = []` instead.

Comment: Hmm. How would you know that `my_dict['a']['b']` should be a `dict` but `my_dict['a']['b']['c'] should be a `list`?

Comment: Here is my solution at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70319015/11397243