# Nesting dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python and I am trying to build a simple REST api with flask. 
I do not understand why this results in an error:

```
boxes = {}
counter = 1
for box in ListOfBoxes:

    boxes['boxes'][counter]['ID']= box.ID
    boxes['boxes'][counter]['name']= box.name 
    boxes['boxes'][counter]['state']= box.state
    boxes['boxes'][counter]['directory']= box.directory
    boxes['boxes'][counter]['provider']= box.provider
    counter +=1 

return jsonify(boxes)
```

While this works:

```
boxes = {}
counter = 1
for box in ListOfBoxes:

    boxes['boxes'] = {}
    boxes['boxes'][counter] = []
    boxes['boxes'][counter].append({'ID': box.ID, 'name':box.name, 'state': box.state, 'directory': box.directory, 'provider': box.provider})
    counter +=1 

return jsonify(boxes)
```

Error being:

```
    File "./flask/app.py", 
line 16, in get_boxes boxes['boxes'][counter]['ID']= box.ID KeyError: 'boxes'
```

When googling and stackoverflowing for answers, mostly the second piece of code is used. At least that's what I understand from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you are trying to access uninitialized values.

```py
boxes = {}
counter = 1
for box in ListOfBoxes:

    boxes['boxes'][counter]['ID']= box.ID
```

Here `boxes` is an empty dict, but `boxes['boxes']` does not exist yet, nor do any of the other levels you're trying to access.

The second example is illustrating how to initialize each new layer in your data structure, before attempting to use it.

```py
# Create a new Dictionary, assign to a key in Dictionary 'boxes'
boxes['boxes'] = {}

# Create a new List, assign to a key in Dictionary we just created
boxes['boxes'][counter] = []

# Now that this List exists, we can use .append() to add to it
boxes['boxes'][counter].append({'ID': box.ID, 'name':box.name, 'state': box.state, 'directory': box.directory, 'provider': box.provider})
```

You received a `KeyError` because you tried to access a dictionary key that did not yet exist: `boxes['boxes']` was never initialized to have a value; therefore, it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is that `boxes` **does not contain a key `'boxes'`. Since you here **do not set `boxes['boxes']`, but you get the element**, and perform operations on that element.

A way to resolve it, is of course immediately insert an element with that key in the dictionary `boxes`, so:

```
boxes = {'boxes':[]}
```

Nevertheless this is still not enough, since again you **get `boxes['boxes'][counter]` to perform operations on that object**. So again, you will have to construct a dictionary.

You can however rewrite your code elegantly using *list-comprehension* and *dictionary literals* to:

```
result = [{'ID': box.ID,'name':box.name,'state':box.state,
           'directory':box.directory,'provider':box.provider}
          for box in ListOfBoxes]
boxes = {'boxes':result}
return jsonify(boxes)
```

If `box` is an **object** and it **contains only the fields discussed above**, you can even use the following *one-liner*:

```
return jsonify({'boxes':[box.__dict__ for box in ListOfBoxes]})
```

since `__dict__` is the dictionary of the object (containing the name of the fields mapped to its values). But this only works under the above discussed conditions.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to implement a default tree is to use a [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def Tree():
    return defaultdict(Tree)
```

Then:

```
boxes = Tree()

boxes['boxes'][5]['provider']= box.provider
```

Comment: I got the same answer… ;-)