# Given a flat list of (parent,child), create a hierarchical dictionary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list with tuples that containing names. These names are parent and child names and I want to create a hierarchical dictionary tree with their names.
For example I have the following list:

```
[('john','marry'),('mike','john'),('mike','hellen'),('john','elisa')]
```

and I want to create this:

```
{
    'mike':{
        'john':{
            'marry':{}
            'elisa':{}
         }
         'hellen':{}
        }
}
```

Comment: What should happen if there was an additional element, say `('elisa', 'mike')`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: I believe this would be wrong because mike is father of john and Hellen and john is Elisa’s father this means that Elisa is mike’s grandchildren and can't be mike's mother.

Comment: `('elisa', 'mike')` can be possible if elisa childname is mike ( new birth )

Comment: I counter this exercise for a job interview and I couldn’t solve it. The exercise is exactly as I posted it ; the only thing I could think of is find the name of grandfather which in this case is mike; after that I can’t think of something to compare the rest of the names.

Comment: indeed ('elisa', 'mike') is possible, so i guess it has to go under Elisa’s name which makes it even more difficult.

Comment: Without getting into the details: Create a topological ordering of your input (the [toposort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toposort/1.5) package is handy for that) and walk down the `zip` of the dependency-chain and the original input to create the final output. Should take something like 20 lines.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming it's well-behaved (no cycles, no duplicate names or multiple parents for one child) you could simply use a "directed graph" and traverse it. To find the root(s) I also used a dictionary containing a boolean that indicates if there is any parent for the name:

```
lst = [('john','marry'), ('mike','john'), ('mike','hellen'), ('john','elisa')]

# Build a directed graph and a list of all names that have no parent
graph = {name: set() for tup in lst for name in tup}
has_parent = {name: False for tup in lst for name in tup}
for parent, child in lst:
    graph[parent].add(child)
    has_parent[child] = True

# All names that have absolutely no parent:
roots = [name for name, parents in has_parent.items() if not parents]

# traversal of the graph (doesn't care about duplicates and cycles)
def traverse(hierarchy, graph, names):
    for name in names:
        hierarchy[name] = traverse({}, graph, graph[name])
    return hierarchy

traverse({}, graph, roots)
# {'mike': {'hellen': {}, 'john': {'elisa': {}, 'marry': {}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

alternative anyway:

```
data = [('john','marry'),('mike','john'),('mike','hellen'),('john','elisa')]

roots = set()
mapping = {}
for parent,child in data:
    childitem = mapping.get(child,None)
    if childitem is None:
        childitem =  {}
        mapping[child] = childitem
    else:
        roots.discard(child)
    parentitem = mapping.get(parent,None)
    if parentitem is None:
        mapping[parent] = {child:childitem}
        roots.add(parent)
    else:
        parentitem[child] = childitem

tree = {id : mapping[id] for id in roots}

print (tree)
```

result:

```
{'mike': 
        {
         'hellen': {}, 
         'john': {
                  'elisa': {}, 
                  'marry': {}}}}
```

Credit to @WillemVanOnsem [Recursively creating a tree hierarchy without using class/object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588346/recursively-creating-a-tree-hierarchy-without-using-class-object)

Comment: .mapping dict is getting updated automatically ,can you tell how its done sample : 
data=[['B', 'A'],['C', 'B']]
1st iteration :
mapping={'B': {}, 'A': {'B': {}}}
2nd iteration :
parentitem={}
after last line of code was executed ,i was expecting parentitem only to change 
parentitem={'C': {}}
The wiered behavious was mapping also got changed automatically even though the last line of code did not manully update the mapping dict how this is working ? how did the mapping dict got changed automatically ?
mapping={'B': {'C': {}}, 'A': {'B': {'C': {}}}, 'C': {}}

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_children(parent, relations):
    children = (r[1] for r in relations if r[0] == parent)
    return {c: get_children(c, relations) for c in children}

the_list = [('john','marry'),('mike','john'),('mike','hellen'),('john','elisa')]

parents, children = map(set, zip(*the_list))
the_tree = {p: get_children(p, the_list) for p in (parents - children)}

print(the_tree)
```