# How can you create dictionaries of keys mapping to lists, with each element in the lists pointing to other lists, in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, tree

For example:

```
d = dict()

#Map "Parent" to a list of "children" values
d["Parent"] = []
d["Parent"].append("Child1")
d["Parent"].append("Child2")
d["Parent"].append("Child3")

#I know the following is wrong, but I want each list that "Parent" maps to, also to map to a list- how would I do this?
d["Parent"]["Child3"] = []
d["Parent"]["Child3"].append("GrandChild1")
```

This would basically look something like a tree (not binary) where there is a top level parent, pointing to its children (could be more than 2), and each can point to its multiple children. Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: Yes, you just need a dictionary instead of a list stored against each key. But how far are you planning to go? Soon enough I think it will become unwieldy

Comment: `d["Child3"].append("GrandChild1")` If you just want to establish the mapping

Comment: let's say it's at most 5 levels of depth

Comment: But d["Child3"].append("GrandChild1") doesn't establish the mapping since it doesn't show the hierarchy of "Parent" to "Child3" to "GrandChild1" (which would look like d["Parent"]["Child3"].append("GrandChild1"), but that's not correct.

Comment: It's basically a tree implementation with a node pointing to its children but I'm not sure how to implement it with dictionaries and lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given a flat list of (parent,child), create a hierarchical dictionary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460653/given-a-flat-list-of-parent-child-create-a-hierarchical-dictionary-tree)

Comment: Using nested `defaultdict`s might be good here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600790/multiple-levels-of-collection-defaultdict-in-python Could potentially be useful for you except you would have `defaultdict(list)` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you're trying to do something like this:

```
d = {}

d["Parent"] = {}

d["Parent"]["Child1"] = {}
d["Parent"]["Child2"] = {}
d["Parent"]["Child3"] = {}

d["Parent"]["Child3"]["GrandChild1"] = {}
d["Parent"]["Child3"]["GrandChild2"] = {}
```

However, where are you going with this? This might not the best way to do this with Python. :-) If you can get your current code to work, you can post it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ afterwards. You will get valuable feedback on how to improve your code.

---

By the way, you can then look at the "branches" of the "tree" with [`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys):

```
print(d.keys())
print(d["Parent"].keys())
print(d["Parent"]["Child3"].keys())
```

Which prints

```
dict_keys(['Parent'])
dict_keys(['Child3', 'Child2', 'Child1'])
dict_keys(['GrandChild2', 'GrandChild1'])
```

Comment: I'm trying to build a tree structure with this, on which I can do a depth-first traversal. Given a JSON list: locations = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "San Francisco Bay Area", "parent_id": None},
  {"id": 2, "name": "San Jose", "parent_id": 3},
  {"id": 3, "name": "South Bay", "parent_id": 1},
  {"id": 4, "name": "San Francisco", "parent_id": 1},
  {"id": 5, "name": "Manhattan", "parent_id": 6},
  {"id": 6, "name": "New York", "parent_id": None}
] I want to be able to print each parent with its children: New York
-Manhattan
San Francisco Bay Area
-San Francisco
-South Bay
—San Jose

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do this in Python than with dicts mapping to lists?

Comment: Not sure how your code solves it. If given a JSON list where each element tells you what its parent id is (for top level parent would be None), I want to be able to create a tree structure from it where each top level parent maps to its children and each of their children (at most depth of 5). With your solution, it's unclear how I would traverse the JSON list and create each mapping. For example, if I'm iterating through the JSON list and see that "GrandChild1" is a child of "Child3" given its parent_id, how would I then know that "Child3" is a child of "Parent" and assign it the way you did?

Comment: Yes, it could be up to 5 levels. But basically the goal is to take that JSON list and output each parent with its children underneath it and add a "-" (hyphen) at each sublevel.

Comment: Thanks @Jayjayyy, that's really helpful. And how would you keep track of each level? For instance I want to sort each level alphabetically and add a hyphen to each level (level 1 would have '-' before the child, level 2 would have '--' before each child, etc

Comment: I guess that would be a depth first traversal after creating the tree and keeping track of each level / using a stack.

Comment: does this method allow you to sort each level alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

Being interested in how to do trees in python, I searched around and came across some example code on GitHub for a [One-line Tree in Python](https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250).

Create a tree from a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
```

Build your tree structure:

```
t = tree()
t['San Francisco Bay Area']['San Francisco']
t['San Francisco Bay Area']['South Bay']['San Jose']
t['New York']['Manhattan']
```

And print it out;

```
import json
print(json.dumps(t))
```

> {"New York": {"Manhattan": {}}, "San Francisco Bay Area": {"San Francisco": {}, "South Bay": {"San Jose": {}}}}

There's further information on iteration and, in the comments, more useful code and suggestions on loading it from json and pretty printing the structure.