# How do I create a recursive function below?

Tags: python-3.x

So each person is represented as a tuple. The first element of the tuple is this person’s name. The second element of
the tuple is a list that contains this person’s children. Each child is represented as a tuple itself. If a person has no
child, the list of his/her children is empty.

For example, if Mary has no child, she is represented as

```
 ('Mary', [])
```

If Jane has two children named Nick and Wendy, and neither Nick nor Wendy has any child, then Jane is represented

```
('Jane', [('Nick', []), ('Wendy', [])])
```

If Mary and Jane are Frank’s children, and Jon is Mary's child, while Nick and Wendy are Jane's children, then Frank is represented as

```
('Frank', [('Mary', [('Jon', [])]), ('Jane', [('Nick', []), ('Wendy', [])])])
```

Thus, how do I write a function that will return a list of members in the family in a hierarchal order? For example

```
get_family_members(('Mary', []))
['Mary']

get_family_members(('Jane', [('Nick', []), ('Wendy', [])]))
['Jane', 'Nick', 'Wendy']

get_family_members(('Frank', [('Mary', [('Jon', [])]), ('Jane', [('Nick', []), ('Wendy', [])])]))
['Frank', 'Mary', 'Jane', 'Jon', 'Nick', 'Wendy',]
```

My attempt:

```
def get_family_members(fam_list): 

    result = []

    if type(fam_list) != list:
        fam_list = [fam_list]

    for i in range(len(fam_list)):
    
        result.append(fam_list[i][0])
    
    for i in range(len(fam_list)):
    
        if fam_list[i][1] != []:

            li = get_family_members(fam_list[i][1])
            result += li
    
    return result
```

Comment: Why a *recursive* function? That makes no sense. And where is your attempt?

Comment: Does [Given a flat list of (parent,child), create a hierarchical dictionary tree [closed]
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460653/given-a-flat-list-of-parent-child-create-a-hierarchical-dictionary-tree) answer your question?

Comment: @itprorh66 How? That's completely different.

Comment: Just uploaded my attempt. If not recursive function, then what do you recommend?

Comment: It's just BFS, right? So a loop over a queue.

Comment: I'm a newbie so forgive me

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output is BFS order, for which a recursive function is inappropriate. So here's a non-recursive one:

```
def get_family_members(person):
    queue = [person]
    return [queue.extend(children) or name
            for name, children in queue]
```

Less hacky non-listcomp version:

```
def get_family_members(person):
    names = []
    queue = [person]
    for name, children in queue:
        names.append(name)
        queue += children
    return names
```

Iterator version:

```
def iter_family_members(person):
    queue = [person]
    for name, children in queue:
        yield name
        queue += children

def get_family_members(person):
    return list(iter_family_members(person))
```

Or with a proper queue:

```
from collections import deque

def iter_family_members(person):
    queue = deque([person])
    while queue:
        name, children = queue.popleft()
        yield name
        queue += children
```