# Creating hierarchical tree from nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, rdf, taxonomy

I have a large RDF file containing about 600,000 records of Wikidata taxonomy. From this file, I am only interested in subclassOf relations (predicate), thus, I ignore all the other statements keeping only "subclassOf" statements. The statement is like:
`a` `is a subclassOf` `b`,
`b` `is a subclassOf` `c`
Like that `c` is a parent of `b` and `b` is a parent of `a`. And any parent can have many children. I want to build hierarchical tree using this taxonomy. 
 I have checked this thread and it almost solved my problem.
[Recursively creating a tree hierarchy without using class/object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588346/recursively-creating-a-tree-hierarchy-without-using-class-object)
However, with this, I am getting tree in dictionary which I want to convert into tree data-structure. Following is what I have tried:

```
data = [['a','x'], ['b','x'], ['c','x'], ['x','y'], ['t','y'], ['y','p'], ['p','q']]

roots = set()
mapping = {}
for child,parent in data:        
    childitem = mapping.get(child,None)
    if childitem is None:
        childitem =  {}
        mapping[child] = childitem
    else:
        roots.discard(child)
    parentitem = mapping.get(parent,None)
    if parentitem is None:
        mapping[parent] = {child:childitem}
        roots.add(parent)
    else:
        parentitem[child] = childitem

for root in roots:
    print(mapping[root])

tree = { id : mapping[id] for id in roots }
print(tree)
```

Output of tree looks as below:

```
{'q': {'p': {'y': {'t': {}, 'x': {'c': {}, 'b': {}, 'a': {}}}}}}
```

I want to convert this dictionary to tree. So e.g. when I say print(mapping['y']), it should give me Node y i.e.

```
q
├── p
    └── y
```

currently, if I say mapping['y'], it gives me subtree rooted at y. I think there is some easy solution for this, but I am not able to understand it. I have found this link as well https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250 to convert dictionary into tree, but not sure how to use it in my case. Alernatively, if anyone knows to directly built a tree from the RDF data that I had given above, then it will be most welcome. Probably python's `anytree API` will solve my issue.

Comment: Do you need a "Tree" class? a way to pretty-print the ancestors of a node for the dictionary-tree you have now? or both?

Comment: Ultimately I need only ancestors (or path till that node). Whether I am getting it using Tree or dictionary is immaterial. Thus, if I can somehow access path for the keys in nested dictionary, my issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind extra O(N) space, you can keep a `parents` dictionary, storing the value parent for every key child. And populate it in main `for` loop.

Finding all ancestors is now pretty easy. Recursively find all ancestors of your parent and append current node to that result.

```
data = [['a','x'], ['b','x'], ['c','x'], ['x','y'], ['t','y'], ['y','p'], ['p','q']]
parents = {} #to store parents
roots = set()
mapping = {}
for child,parent in data:
    parents[child] = parent #populate parents
    childitem = mapping.get(child,None)
    ................................

def ancestors(node): #the ancestor-finding function
    if not node: return []
    return ancestors(parents.get(node))+[node]

def first_k_ancestor(node,k=5):
    ances = ancestors(node)
    ances.reverse()
    return ances[:k]


print(ancestors('a'))
```

which prints:

```
['q', 'p', 'y']
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. And what if I want this hierarchy in reverse order and only till level 3. E.g. For node 'a' I want only [a, x, y] and Not [a,x,y,p,q]

Comment: Is performance an issue? and can that 3 might change i.e top 5 ancestors maybe?

Comment: Performance is not really an issue, because creating this hierarchy is a one time process and later I am going to store required keys and their respective path (as value) in dictionary which I will access often. And I actually want 5 ancestors only, I said 3 to make this example work. In real data I can have like 50 ancestors among which I will need only last 5.

Comment: see if `first_k_ancestors` do the job. which automatically selects top 5, but u can change that by passing a 2nd parameter

Comment: Okay. I will try this. Thanks :)