# Are there packages to register/identify schemas for a Pandas data analysis workflow?

Tags: pandas, schema, workflow

I'm using Pandas to automate analysis of a variety of different *3rd party reports*. Most are in `csv` format.

Assuming only correct files are loaded into the program, I need to:

- identify the origin of the report (3rd party), based on

  - schema
  - predictable column values
- store historical reports of same origin,
- return origin, maybe some other thing-ys

I only need to manage 10 reports in the beginning. I imagine it could grow into identifying upwards of several hundred--noting that a flat file and some dictionaries couldn't handle. But why reinvent the wheel, ...

Are there packages to register/identify schemas for a Pandas data analysis workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a first pass solution which I'll offer as answer. I've implemented a class-based solution with `defaultdict`. Here's the basic outline:

- [Register](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) class oop structure to handle and access **schemas** in my scripts:

  - `Report(object)`
  - `ChildReport(Report)`
- ['vividict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries) or multi-dimensional dictionary  structure to handle the collection of reports using Python's `defaultdict`:

  - `client_reports['date']['type'] = ChildReport(self)`
- `ReportsManager(object)` class. Initializes the `vividict`, and collects multiple methods for accessing and managing the collections--one for each client.
- Python's Pickle module to store the `ReportManager` object--one for each client.

I have a few doubts about how I structured the `defaultdict` with the `ReportsManager` class. It's a start.